# Why prefer two's complement over sign-and-magnitude for signed numbers?

Tags: binary, math, twos-complement, negative-number, internal-representation

I'm just curious if there's a reason why in order to represent -1 in binary, two's complement is used: flipping the bits and adding 1?

-1 is represented by 11111111 (two's complement) rather than (to me more intuitive) 10000001 which is binary 1 with first bit as negative flag.

Disclaimer: I don't rely on binary arithmetic for my job!

Comment: FWIW, your "intuitive" method of using a sign-bit is ocassionally used -- for example, most computers use a sign-bit when representing floating point numbers.

Comment: @Adisak It's called signed magnitude

Comment: I've always associated sign-and-magnitude representation with integers since Floating Point numbers contain three components: a sign, an exponent, and a mantissa (often with an implicit '1').  But I guess it's easy enough to treat the exponent and mantissa as magnitude as long as one realizes they are not strictly linear.

Comment: [Here's an article](http://kipirvine.com/asm/workbook/floating_tut.htm) discussing how floating-point numbers are stored in binary, for those who are curious about @Adisak's remarks.

Comment: Just saw a nice video explaining this
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHB7jFjESLY

Answer (score 380, accepted):

It's done so that addition doesn't need to have any special logic for dealing with negative numbers. Check out [the article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Say you have two numbers, 2 and -1. In your "intuitive" way of representing numbers, they would be `0010` and `1001`, respectively (I'm sticking to 4 bits for size). In the [two's complement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1049722/) way, they are `0010` and `1111`. Now, let's say I want to add them.

Two's complement addition is very simple. You add numbers normally and any carry bit at the end is discarded. So they're added as follows:

```
  0010
+ 1111
=10001
= 0001 (discard the carry)
```

`0001` is 1, which is the expected result of "2+(-1)".

But in your "intuitive" method, adding is more complicated:

```
  0010
+ 1001
= 1011
```

Which is -3, right? Simple addition doesn't work in this case. You need to note that one of the numbers is negative and use a different algorithm if that's the case.

For this "intuitive" storage method, subtraction is a different operation than addition, requiring additional checks on the numbers before they can be added. Since you want the most basic operations (addition, subtraction, etc) to be as fast as possible, you need to store numbers in a way that lets you use the simplest algorithms possible.

Additionally, in the "intuitive" storage method, there are two zeroes:

```
0000  "zero"
1000  "negative zero"
```

Which are intuitively the same number but have two different values when stored. Every application will need to take extra steps to make sure that non-zero values are also not negative zero.

There's another bonus with storing ints this way, and that's when you need to extend the width of the register the value is being stored in. With two's complement, storing a 4-bit number in an 8-bit register is a matter of repeating its most significant bit:

```
    0001 (one, in four bits)
00000001 (one, in eight bits)
    1110 (negative two, in four bits)
11111110 (negative two, in eight bits)
```

It's just a matter of looking at the sign bit of the smaller word and repeating it until it pads the width of the bigger word.

With your method you would need to clear the existing bit, which is an extra operation in addition to padding:

```
    0001 (one, in four bits)
00000001 (one, in eight bits)
    1010 (negative two, in four bits)
10000010 (negative two, in eight bits)
```

You still need to set those extra 4 bits in both cases, but in the "intuitive" case you need to clear the 5th bit as well. It's one tiny extra step in one of the most fundamental and common operations present in every application.

Comment: I agree. 2's complement works. But how did we arrive at it in the first place? If suppose I need to arrive at this notation, what would the thought process be. I think arriving at 2's complement has to be more than just luck, isn't it?

Comment: Also, why is there no 2's complement counterpart for floats?

Comment: Can anyone tell me how does computer know that it's 2s complement and not any other poisitive binary number?

Comment: @HarshalGajjar to computer it does not matter whether it is 2 complement or not. For it, it is just a binary number and it simply perform the operation. However the 2's complement come into picture while saving the data in binary. So if you have a negative number, it is automatically represented in 2s compliment and stored, and positive number is saved as it is. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Lazer check this article to know `how we arrived at 2s compliment the first place.` http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html

Comment: non-widening multiplication is also the same and you don't need separate circuitry for that

Comment: Thanks for an informative post .. Is my understanding correct - When I say normal 0100 then it is +8 and when I say two's complement 0100 then it is -12 ?? In Java, negative numbers are stored as 2's complement ??

Comment: @hagrawal, no. 0100 is +4. The bits are -8, 4, 2 and 1, so 0100 is 0*-8 + 1*4 + 0*2 + 0*1 = 4. This is true in two's complement or "normal".

Comment: Sorry, I goofed up .. 2's complement of 0100(4) will be 1100. Now 1100 is 12 if I say normally. So, when I say normal 1100 then it is 12, but when I say 2's complement 1100 then it is -4? Also, in Java when 1100 (lets assume 4 bits for now) is stored then how it is determined if it is +12 or -4 ??

Comment: Java only has signed integer types as far as I'm aware, so it always treats it in its two's complement interpretation. In other languages, how the value is treated depends on how the code treats it. There's nothing to tell you that a block of memory is a signed or unsigned integer or a double or a string or something else. The raw data is whatever type you choose to interpret it as.

Comment: @hagrawal The system establishes how to interpret a sequence of bytes through types. [Below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32363667/5062064) you can find a more elaborate version of this comment.

Comment: @Welbog how can `1111`be negative one . It does not when i try to convert it into decimal. I am so confused?

Comment: @Welbog If i take most significant bit as the identifier whether this number is positive or negative . Then `1111` MSB is `1` so number is negative then how does the remaining part tells that it is `-1`. I mean it does not add up to `1` so that the result becomes `-1` .MSB telling that the number is negative. What Really Happens?

Comment: @Suraj, I suggest looking at the Wikipedia article on two's complement for the full answer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement. The short answer is the MSB `1` indicates `-8`, and the remaining three `1`s indicate `4`, `2`, and `1`, respectively, so `-8+4+2+1 = -1`.

Comment: @Welbog I Just want to know is 2's complement always follow , i mean if i have `int x = -4` , and i then do `printf("%d" , x)` how does it get  interpreted ? Also what is the difference between `unsigned int` and `signed int` and `%d` and `%u` ... this has been bugging me for a long time now .Thanks.

Comment: @Suraj, Two's complement only applies to signed integers. Unsigned integers don't need to represent negative numbers, and two's complement is a way of representing negative numbers. `%d` forces it to print as a signed integer, and `%u` forced it to print as an unsigned integer.

Comment: @Welbog If i write char x = -1 and unsigned char x = -1 , what would be the underlying representation ?

Comment: If i write `signed int a = -1` , then `-1` in 2's complement form is `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` and then when i use `%d` to interpret it it prints `-1` and `%u` , it prints `4294967295` and when i write `signed int a = 2` , it prints `2` when i use `%d` and also when i use `%u` . If 2 would be in two's complement it would be `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111101` , and then it would be a very diffrenet answer , what i really want to ask is when does 2's complement happen is it depend on `-` sign or it happens for every integer if type is signed int which must not be the case here.

Comment: Also when  i write `unsigned int a = -1` , then `-1` in 2's complement form is `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` and then when i use `%d` to interpret it it prints `-1` and `%u` , it prints `4294967295` .So if a number is negative it is alwasys stored as 2's complement no matter the type unsigned or signed , is that right ... this question has been bugging me for  a while , i would have asked a new question on stackoverflow , but my experience tells me it is not very friendly to beginner  , so i am afraid to write a new question.

Comment: @Suraj, I think you have some incorrect assumptions about two's complement and signed and unsigned numbers. In memory, there is no difference between a signed and unsigned number. The `signed char x = -1` and `unsigned char y = -1` have the same representation in memory. The same ones and zeroes in the same order. The only difference between the two is how they're interpreted. When stored in an unsigned variable, they're interpreted as unsigned. When stored in signed variables, they're signed. When printed as signed, they're signed, etc. The same is true for `un/signed char z = 2`.

Comment: @Suraj, you should always ask new questions as questions. This site is helpful to new users if their questions are clear. New users often have a hard time forming their thoughts into a clear question, but get the hang of it when looking at other questions. If you want to ask your question as a question and link it here, I will do my best to answer it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41407568/why-do-we-have-unsigned-and-signed-int-type-in-c

Comment: But with two's complement (assuming 4bit ints), 7+1 = -8, Isn't that counterintuitive ?

Comment: @Tanishq-Banyal: yes, but it's a small price to pay on the edge case to enable a much easier time, computationally, for the average case.

Answer (score 20):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) says it all:

> The two's-complement system has the advantage of not requiring that the addition and subtraction circuitry examine the signs of the operands to determine whether to add or subtract. This property makes the system both simpler to implement and capable of easily handling higher precision arithmetic. Also, zero has only a single representation, obviating the subtleties associated with negative zero, which exists in ones'-complement systems.

In other words, adding is the same, wether or not the number is negative.

Comment: Sir , if i write char a = 12 ; and unsigned char b = 12 , is the underlying bit patter same , what really happens ?

Comment: Nothing changes when writes or reads. Only applicable when addition or subtraction.

Answer (score 19):

Even though this question is old , let me put in my 2 cents.

Before I explain this ,lets get back to basics. 2' complement is 1's complement + 1 .
Now what is 1's complement and what is its significance in addition.

Sum of any n-bit number and its 1's complement gives you the highest possible number that can be represented by those n-bits.
Example:

```
 0010 (2 in 4 bit system)
+1101 (1's complement of 2)
___________________________
 1111  (the highest number that we can represent by 4 bits)
```

Now what will happen if we try to add 1 more to the result. It will results in an overflow.

The result will be `1 0000` which is 0 ( as we are working with 4 bit numbers , (the 1 on left is an overflow )

So ,

```
Any n-bit number + its 1's complement = max n-bit number
Any n-bit number + its 1'complement + 1 = 0 ( as explained above, overflow will occur as we are adding 1 to max n-bit number)
```

Someone then decided to call 1's complement + 1 as 2'complement. So the above statement becomes:
Any n'bit number + its 2's complement = 0
which means 2's complement of a number = - (of that number)

All this yields one more question , why can we use only the (n-1) of the n bits to represent positive number and why does the left most nth bit represent sign (0 on the leftmost bit means +ve number , and 1 means -ve number ) . eg why do we use only the first 31 bits of an int in java to represent positive number if the 32nd bit is 1 , its a -ve number.

```
 1100 (lets assume 12 in 4 bit system)
+0100(2's complement of 12)
___________________________
```

1 0000  (result is zero , with the carry 1 overflowing)

Thus the system of (n + 2'complement of n) = 0 , still works. The only ambiguity here is 2's complement of 12 is 0100 which ambiguously also represents +8 , other than representing -12 in 2s complement system.

This problem will be solved if positive numbers always have a 0 in their left most bit. In that case their 2's complement  will always have a 1 in their left most bit , and we wont have the ambiguity of the same set of bits representing a 2's complement number as well as a +ve number.

Comment: +1'ed. It was information, however in the end it I am not sure why you wanted have the approach of most significant bit to represent whether it is a positive or negative number. It has many issue like 0 will have 2 representations - 0000(+) and 1000(-) .. Also addition and subtraction cannot be done using same algorithm. When you say an normal 0100 then it is +8 and when you say two's complement 0100 then it is -12 ..

Answer (score 9):

[Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) allows addition and subtraction to be done in the normal way (like you wound for unsigned numbers). It also prevents -0 (a separate way to represent 0 that would not be equal to 0 with the normal bit-by-bit method of comparing numbers).

Answer (score 8):

Two's complement allows negative and positive numbers to be added together without any special logic.

If you tried to add 1 and -1 using your method
 10000001   (-1)
+00000001   (1)
you get
 10000010  (-2)

Instead, by using two's complement, we can add

11111111   (-1)
+00000001   (1)
you get
 00000000   (0)

The same is true for subtraction.

Also, if you try to subtract 4 from 6 (two positive numbers) you can 2's complement 4 and add the two together 6 + (-4) = 6 - 4 = 2

This means that subtraction and addition of both positive and negative numbers can all be done by the same circuit in the cpu.

Answer (score 6):

this is to simplify sums and differences of numbers. a sum of a negative number and a positive one codified in 2's complements is the same as summing them up in the normal way.

Answer (score 6):

The usual implementation of the operation is "flip the bits and add 1", but there's another way of defining it that probably makes the rationale clearer. 2's complement is the form you get if you take the usual unsigned representation where each bit controls the next power of 2, and just make the most significant term negative.

Taking an 8-bit value a<sub>7</sub> a<sub>6</sub> a<sub>5</sub> a<sub>4</sub> a<sub>3</sub> a<sub>2</sub> a<sub>1</sub> a<sub>0</sub>

The usual unsigned binary interpretation is:
2<sup>7</sup>*a<sub>7</sub> + 2<sup>6</sup>*a<sub>6</sub> + 2<sup>5</sup>*a<sub>5</sub> + 2<sup>4</sup>*a<sub>4</sub> + 2<sup>3</sup>*a<sub>3</sub> + 2<sup>2</sup>*a<sub>2</sub> + 2<sup>1</sup>*a<sub>1</sub> + 2<sup>0</sup>*a<sub>0</sub>
11111111 = 128 + 64 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 255

The two's complement interpretation is:
-2<sup>7</sup>*a<sub>7</sub> + 2<sup>6</sup>*a<sub>6</sub> + 2<sup>5</sup>*a<sub>5</sub> + 2<sup>4</sup>*a<sub>4</sub> + 2<sup>3</sup>*a<sub>3</sub> + 2<sup>2</sup>*a<sub>2</sub> + 2<sup>1</sup>*a<sub>1</sub> + 2<sup>0</sup>*a<sub>0</sub>
11111111 = -128 + 64 + 32 + 16 + 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = -1

None of the other bits change meaning at all, and carrying into a<sub>7</sub> is "overflow" and not expected to work, so pretty much all of the arithmetic operations work without modification (as others have noted). Sign-magnitude generally inspect the sign bit and use different logic.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on others answers:

In two's complement

- Adding is the same mechanism as plain positive integers adding.
- Subtracting doesn't change too
- Multiplication too!

Division does require a different mechanism.

All these are true because two's complement is just normal modular arithmetic, where we choose to look at some numbers as negative by subtracting the modulo.

Comment: Not that [only non-widening multiplication is the same](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14063665/995714). But as most high level languages don't support widening multiplication without explicit cast, the result will be the same in those languages.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Widening multiplication will usually be the same, but results for signed and unsigned multiply are only guaranteed to be the same if the result would fit in the range of a signed int.  Some compilers like gcc, given something like `unsigned mul(unsigned short x, unsigned short y) { return x*y; }` [16-bit short; 32-bit int] will occasionally generate code that will malfunction if the product is larger than 2147483647.

Answer (score 3):

Reading the answers to this question, I came across this comment [edited].

> 2's complement of 0100(4) will be 1100. Now 1100 is 12 if I say normally. So,
>   when I say normal 1100 then it is 12, but when I say 2's complement 1100 then
>   it is -4? Also, in Java when 1100 (lets assume 4 bits for now) is stored then
>   how it is determined if it is +12 or -4 ?? – hagrawal Jul 2 at 16:53

In my opinion, the question asked in this comment is quite interesting and so I'd like first of all to rephrase it and then to provide an answer and an example.

QUESTION – How can the system establish how one or more adjacent bytes have to be interpreted? In particular, how can the system establish whether a given sequence of bytes is a plain binary number or a 2's complement number?

ANSWER – The system establishes how to interpret a sequence of bytes through types.
Types define

- how many bytes have to be considered
- how those bytes have to be interpreted

EXAMPLE – Below we assume that

- `char`'s are 1 byte long
- `short`'s are 2 bytes long
- `int`'s and `float`'s are 4 bytes long

Please note that these sizes are specific to my system. Although pretty common, they can be different from system to system. If you're curious of what they are on your system, use the [sizeof operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof).

First of all we define an array containing 4 bytes and initialize all of them to the binary number `10111101`, corresponding to the hexadecimal number `BD`.

```c
// BD(hexadecimal) = 10111101 (binary)
unsigned char   l_Just4Bytes[ 4 ]   =   { 0xBD, 0xBD, 0xBD, 0xBD };
```

Then we read the array content using different types.

#### `unsigned char` and `signed char`

```c
// 10111101 as a PLAIN BINARY number equals 189
printf( "l_Just4Bytes as unsigned char  -> %hi\n", *( ( unsigned char* )l_Just4Bytes ) );

// 10111101 as a 2'S COMPLEMENT number equals -67
printf( "l_Just4Bytes as signed char    -> %i\n", *( ( signed char* )l_Just4Bytes ) );
```

#### `unsigned short` and `short`

```c
// 1011110110111101 as a PLAIN BINARY number equals 48573
printf( "l_Just4Bytes as unsigned short -> %hu\n", *( ( unsigned short* )l_Just4Bytes ) );

// 1011110110111101 as a 2'S COMPLEMENT number equals -16963
printf( "l_Just4Bytes as short          -> %hi\n", *( ( short* )l_Just4Bytes ) );
```

#### `unsigned int`, `int` and `float`

```c
// 10111101101111011011110110111101 as a PLAIN BINARY number equals 3183328701
printf( "l_Just4Bytes as unsigned int   -> %u\n", *( ( unsigned int* )l_Just4Bytes ) );

// 10111101101111011011110110111101 as a 2'S COMPLEMENT number equals -1111638595
printf( "l_Just4Bytes as int            -> %i\n", *( ( int* )l_Just4Bytes ) );

// 10111101101111011011110110111101 as a IEEE 754 SINGLE-PRECISION number equals -0.092647
printf( "l_Just4Bytes as float          -> %f\n", *( ( float* )l_Just4Bytes ) );
```

The 4 bytes in RAM (`l_Just4Bytes[ 0..3 ]`) always remain exactly the same. The only thing that changes is how we interpret them.

Again, *we* tell the system *how* to interpret them through *types*.

For instance, above we have used the following types to interpret the contents of the `l_Just4Bytes` array

- `unsigned char`: 1 byte in plain binary
- `signed char`: 1 byte in 2's complement
- `unsigned short`: 2 bytes in plain binary notation
- `short`: 2 bytes in 2's complement
- `unsigned int`: 4 bytes in plain binary notation
- `int`: 4 bytes in 2's complement
- `float`: 4 bytes in IEEE 754 single-precision notation

---

[EDIT] This post has been edited after the comment by user4581301. Thank you for taking the time to drop those few helpful lines!

Comment: That code blob needs an edit so readers don't have to keep scrolling back and forth. Better, that massive comment at the top should become plain old text  and let the renderer take care of the formatting. You should also add a caveat to the bit near the end where you discuss  the sizes and formatting because the sizes are not fixed.

Comment: +1. One thing you might consider doing, @mw215, is making this question/answer pair a Community Wiki entry on its own, because it's useful for people who might be interested in raw byte interpretation outside of the context of two's complement math.

Comment: I Just want to know is 2's complement always follow , i mean if i have `int x = -4` , and i then do `printf("%d" , x)` how does it get  interpreted ? Also what is the difference between `unsigned int` and `signed int` and `%d` and `%u` ... this has been bugging me for a long time now .Thanks.

Comment: @Suraj Jain When using `int` types, the `signed` modifier is default. This means that `int` and `signed int` are exactly the same type. Thus the two definitions `int i = -4;` and `signed int i = -4;` have the same meaning.

Comment: @Suraj Jain The system establishes how to interpret a sequence of bytes through types. Types define: how many bytes have to be considered and how those bytes have to be interpreted. An `int` is 4 bytes in [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) and an `unsigned int` is 4 bytes in [plain binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number) notation (check the actual type size on your system using the `sizeof` operator).

Comment: @Suraj Jain So, for instance, after `int x = -4;` you would have the following adjacent 4 bytes somewhere in RAM: `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111100`; while after `unsigned int x = 4;` the 4 adjacent bytes in RAM would be `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000100`.

Comment: @Suraj Jain As for `printf` formatting, you can use both `%d` and `%u` with either an `int` or an `unsigned int`. In fact, if you use `%d` "The `int` argument is converted to signed decimal in the style [−]dddd" and an analogous conversion takes place using `%u`. `d` and `u` are called "conversion specifiers" in the [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Two's complement is used because it is simpler to implement in circuitry and also does not allow a negative zero.

If there are x bits, two's complement will range from +(2^x/2+1) to -(2^x/2). One's complement will run from +(2^x/2) to -(2^x/2), but will permit a negative zero (0000 is equal to 1000 in a 4 bit 1's complement system).

Comment: Yes, having a negative zero is a waste.

Answer (score 2):

There are three common methods to represent negative representation of a number which are as below

- Signed bit
- 1's Complement
- 2's Complement

To understand why 2's Complement is preferred over other two, let us see what limitations other methods posses.

**Problem while using Signed bit:**

- In **Signed bit representation**, leading bit(first bit from left) will decide whether the number is negative or positive. If leading bit is 1, negative number is represented and if zero positive.
- Problem with this approach would be **two representation of zero** i.e minus and plus zero. This will reduce the range as well as create confusion in arithmetic operations.

**Problem while using 1's Complement:**

- In 1's Complement, negative number is represented by reversing the bits of its positive representation.
- Problem is same as there will two representations of zero i.e minus and plus zero. This will reduce the range as well as create confusion in arithmetic operations.

**How 2's Complement solve the issue**

- 2's Complement means negative number is represented by reversing the bits of its positive representation and then adding 1 to it. So using 2's complement there is **only one representation of zero**.

**Note:** Any carry bit at the end is discarded while calculating 2's Complement.

- **Arithmetic operations are easier to perform**, because 2’s complement form is derived from idea of 0-x where x is the number (positive form).
- Leading bit is always 1 for the negative number and 0 for the positive number.

Answer (score 1):

It's worthwhile to note that on some early adding machines, before the days of digital computers, subtraction would be performed by having the operator enter values using a different colored set of legends on each key (so each key would enter nine minus the number to be subtracted), and press a special button would would assume a carry into a calculation.  Thus, on a six-digit machine, to subtract 1234 from a value, the operator would hit keys that would normally indicate "998,765" and hit a button to add that value plus one to the calculation in progress.  Two's complement arithmetic is simply the binary equivalent of that earlier "ten's-complement" arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of performing subtraction by the complement method is reduction in the hardware
complexity.The are no need of the different digital circuit for addition and subtraction.both 
 addition and subtraction are performed by adder only.

Answer (score 1):

I have a slight addendum that is important in some situations: two's compliment is the only representation that is possible given these constraints:

- Unsigned numbers and two's compliment are [commutative rings with identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_ring). There is a homomorphism between them.
- They share the same representation, with a different branch cut for negative numbers, (hence, why addition and multiplication are the same between them.)
- The high bit determines the sign.

To see why, it helps to reduce the cardinality; for example, Z_4.

[image: Two different Z_4 representations.]

*Sign and magnitude* and *ones' compliment* both do not form a ring with the same number of elements; a symptom is the double zero. It is therefore difficult to work with on the edges; to be mathematically consistent, they require checking for overflow or [trap representations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55044324/2472827).

Answer (score 0):

Well, your intent is not really to reverse all bits of your binary number. It is actually to subtract each its digit from 1. It's just a fortunate coincidence that subtracting 1 from 1 results in 0 and subtracting 0 from 1 results in 1. So flipping bits is effectively carrying out this subtraction.

But why are you finding each digit's difference from 1? Well, you're not. Your actual intent is to compute the given binary number's difference from another binary number which has the same number of digits but contains only 1's. For example if your number is 10110001, when you flip all those bits, you're effectively computing (11111111 - 10110001).

This explains the first step in the computation of Two's Complement. Now let's include the second step -- adding 1 -- also in the picture.

Add 1 to the above binary equation:

11111111 - 10110001 + 1

What do you get? This:

100000000 - 10110001

This is the final equation. And by carrying out those two steps you're trying to find this, final difference: the binary number subtracted from another binary number with one extra digit and containing zeros except at the most signification bit position.

But why are we hankerin' after this difference really? Well, from here on, I guess it would be better if you read the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Answer (score 0):

We perform only addition operation for both addition and subtraction. We add the second operand to the first operand for addition. For subtraction we add the 2's complement of the second operand to the first operand.

With a 2's complement representation we do not need separate digital components for subtraction—only adders and complementers are used.

Answer (score 0):

A major advantage of two's-complement representation which hasn't yet been mentioned here is that the lower bits of a two's-complement sum, difference, or product are dependent *only* upon the corresponding bits of the operands.  The reason that the 8 bit signed value for -1 is `11111111` is that subtracting *any* integer whose lowest 8 bits are `00000001` from any other integer whose lowest 8 bits are `0000000` will yield an integer whose lowest 8 bits are `11111111`.  Mathematically, the value -1 would be an infinite string of 1's, but all values within the range of a particular integer type will either be all 1's or all 0's past a certain point, so it's convenient for computers to "sign-extend" the most significant bit of a number as though it represented an infinite number of 1's or 0's.

Two's-complement is just about the only signed-number representation that works well when dealing with types larger than a binary machine's natural word size, since when performing addition or subtraction, code can fetch the lowest chunk of each operand, compute the lowest chunk of the result, and store that, then load the next chunk of each operand, compute the next chunk of the result, and store that, etc.  Thus, even a processor which requires all additions and subtractions to go through a single 8-bit register can handle 32-bit signed numbers reasonably efficiently (slower than with a 32-bit register, of course, but still workable).

When using of the any other signed representations allowed by the C Standard, every bit of the result could potentially be affected by any bit of the operands, making it necessary to either hold an entire value in registers at once or else follow computations with an extra step that would, in at least some cases, require reading, modifying, and rewriting each chunk of the result.

Comment: Please Format Your Answer In Paragraph and mark code as code , it would be more readable and you will get upvote.

Comment: @SurajJain: Is that better?

Comment: Yeah , better than what it earlier was , i want to ask you one thing what is the difference between signed char a = 1 and unsigned char a = 1  , how are they represented in memory.

Comment: @SurajJain: On two's-complement systems where "char" is smaller than "int" [i.e. the vast majority of systems], the signed and unsigned char types will behave identically *except* that signed types will be sign-extended when read and unsigned types won't.  On such a system, storing the value 194 or -62 into a signed char will write the same bit pattern as storing 194 or -62 into an unsigned char (i.e. 11000010).  Reading that bit pattern from a signed char will yield -62, and reading it from an unsigned char will yield 194.

Comment: sign-extended means ?

Comment: @SurajJain: Copying the value of the top bit of a shorter type to all of the upper bits of a longer type.  So a system with 16-bit "int", reading the signed char value 11000010 would yield the int value 1111111111000010.

Comment: Just want to know is 2's complement always follow , i mean if i have int x = -4 , and i then do printf("%d" , x) how does it get interpreted ? Also what is the difference between unsigned int and signed int and %d and %u ... this has been bugging me for a long time now .Thanks

Comment: @SurajJain: If the situation described, the `printf` will output -4.  Sane implementations on commonplace hardware will treat signed values from `INT_MIN` to -1 as equivalent to unsigned values from `INT_MAX+1u` to `UINT_MAX`, but the Standard would allow a compiler to do anything it likes if `%u` or `%x` is used on a value of type `int` or "%i` or `%d` is used on a value of type `unsigned`.

Comment: If i write `signed int a = -1` , then ` -1` in 2's complement form is `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` and then when i use `%d` to interpret it it prints -1 and %u , it prints `4294967295` and when i write `signed int a = 2` , it prints 2 when i use `%d` and also when i use `%u` . If `2` would be in two's complement it would be `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111101` , and then it would be a very diffr answer , what i really want to ask is when does 2's complement happen is it depend on - sign or it happens for every integer if type is `signed int` which must not be the case here.

Comment: @SurajJain: Two's-complement is relevant for values less than zero or beyond the positive range of an integer's type.  Non-negative values which are within the range of a signed integer type will simply behave as numbers.

Comment: how does computer knows when to do 2's bit complement and when to not , i have many doubts , if you would be able to clear it , it would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

One satisfactory answer of why Two2's Complement is used to represent negative numbers rather than One's Complement system is that 
                        Two's Complement system solves the problem of **multiple representations of 0** and the need for **end-around-carry** which exist in the One's complement system of representing negative numbers.

For more information Visit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

For End-around-carry Visit 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-around_carry

Comment: actually, if you have a decimal point and are explicit about what all bits are:  "0..0000.1111..1" means that all left-most unstated bits are 0, and all right-most unstated bits are 1, and therefore the "..1" means that a carry is triggered.  Therefore it's (mechanically) "0.0001.0000..0".  It means that "1..1111.1111..1" is equal to zero!  This also means that to negate an integer, you really do just flip its bits.  But it now applies to representable fractions.

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of representations those are:

1. unsigned number representation
2. signed number representation
3. one's complement  representation
4. Two's complement  representation

-Unsigned number representation used to represent only positive numbers

-Signed number representation used to represent positive as well as a negative number. In Signed number representation MSB bit represents sign bit and rest bits represents the number. When MSB is 0 means number is positive and When MSB is 1 means number is negative.

**Problem with Signed number representation is that there are two values for 0.**

**Problem with one's complement representation is that there are two values for 0.**

But if we use Two's complement representation then there will only one value for 0 that's why we represent negative numbers in two's complement form.

Source:[Why negative numbers are stored in two's complement form bytesofgigabytes](http://www.bytesofgigabytes.com/embedded/why-negative-numbers-are-stored-in-twos-complement-form-in-computer/)