# Why Two's Complement?

Tags: computer-science, twos-complement

I'm writing a tutorial to teach kids (ages 9 to 13) about programming. I started with computers themselves, they don't have that much to do with computer science, it's more about the process involved with a solution to a computational problem.

With that starting point, I'm guiding them toward an understanding that machines can help us with certain computational problems. People are great at abstract thinking and imagination, but computers are AWESOME at following a well-specified routine. They can do it again and again, at amazing speed!

Representing numbers in binary format has already been covered in my tutorial. But how do you represent negative numbers? There are so many ways to do this, in any notational system, but the system chosen for computers is for a very specific reason: to reduce the amount of machinery involved with adding signed integer values. We don't want to have to construct and build separate chips just to handle negative numbers, we want to use the same chips we have been using for natural number arithmetic!

If someone asked you on the street (as totally unrealistic as this seems) "how do computers represent negative numbers, and why do they represent them this way?"

My specific questions:

> 1. How do computers represent negative numbers?
> 2. Why do computers represent negative numbers this way?

I would guess that this many experienced developers would have to think about this a bit. Some might not even be able to come up with an answer. I'm not trying to be pompous, this is from actual experience, I've asked professional developers this question and they can't answer it. They draw a blank stare. Give them JBoss and JavaBeans and they will steamroll you with confidence. So funny! I too struggle with this question, I have to remind myself of the answers every time and I need a piece of paper or white board to work out a solution. What I'm hoping is to guide students toward a better understanding of the machine they are working with.

Comment: There is a nice explanation here.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Comment: Also, for future Googlers, @Welbog [smashed this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1125317/1717828).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Advantage of 2's complement over 1's complement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054213/advantage-of-2s-complement-over-1s-complement)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> 1.How do computers represent negative numbers?

Take the positive value, invert all bits and add one.

> 2.Why do computers represent negative numbers this way?

It makes easy to add 7 in -7 and came up with a zero. The bit operations are fast.

---

**How does it make it easy?**

Take the 7 and -7 example. If you represent 7 as `00000111`, to find -7 invert all bits and add one:

```
11111000 -> 11111001
```

Now you can add following standard math rules:

```
  00000111
+ 11111001
-----------
  00000000
```

For the computer this operation is relatively easy, as it involves basically comparing bit by bit and carrying one.

If instead you represented -7 as `10000111`, this won't make sense:

```
  00000111
+ 10000111
-----------
  10001110 (-14)
```

To add them, you will involve more complex rules like analyzing the first bit, and transforming the values.

And don't forget what @trashgod said, in 2's complement you have only one zero. To check it:

> `00000000`
>   `11111111` (invert all bits)
>   `00000000` (add one)

Differently from `00000000` (*0*) being equal to `10000000` (*-0*)

Comment: The person on the street would not know what bits were, or what it meant to invert them.

Comment: ok nice comments, thanks for the feedback. But imagine if you're an 8 year old trying to understand this. "It makes it easy" isn't enough. They will immediately come back with, "how does it make it easier, why, i don't get it". They're incredibly smart, just like you and I were at that age. Your answer is good but I need something more accessible to a child.

Comment: @agf, if someone asked me that on the street I'd answer exactly like this. The person probably knows what a bit is if the question is about 2's complement.

Comment: agf and @sidyll, this is exactly what I was looking for. Yes you'd have to be a geek to know about bits and numerical notational systems, but that's all not as important as getting a kid interested in what he or she might be naturally adept at excelling in.

Comment: @dvanaria start with explaining how positive numbers are represented in binary. **You cannot understand two's complement without first understanding this.**

Comment: @dvanaria It would also help appeal to their intuition if you demonstrated that `-(-5) = 5` for example. That will "prove" to them that adding 1 isn't destructive and that you get the original number back even though you're adding 1 twice.

Comment: Negative integers not all negative numbers are represented using 2's complement. IEEE 754 doesn't use 2's complement in any way. Little detail i know but still it matters.

Answer (score 7):

**How do computers represent negative numbers?**

Computers represent negative numbers by calculating the result that you would get if you subtracted that number from zero, using their normal rules for subtraction.  That is, to find what `-5` looks like in binary, you subtract `5` (in binary) from `0` (in binary):

```
0  0  0  0 -
0  1  0  1
----------

              (borrow)
-> 1 -> 1 -> 1 ->10 -
   0    1    0    1
   ----------------
   1    0    1    1
```

..so `-5` looks like `1011` in binary.

**Why do computers represent negative numbers this way?**

Because doing it this way means that when the computer is adding and subtracting numbers, it doesn't have to check if some of them are negative or not: the maths works out anyway.  This makes the computer simpler, and simpler computers are cheaper to build.

Comment: This was a way easier explanation then the rest of the others. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

> Why do computers represent negative numbers this way?

Two big reasons I can think of:

- Simplicity of basic arithmetic operations. You don't have to worry about inspecting the sign bit to decide whether to add or subtract.
- Uniqueness of representation. It's nice to not have to worry about negative zero since there is no way to represent negative zero in two's complement.

[From Wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

> The two's-complement system has the advantage of not requiring that the addition and subtraction circuitry examine the signs of the operands to determine whether to add or subtract. This property makes the system both simpler to implement and capable of easily handling higher precision arithmetic. Also, zero has only a single representation, obviating the subtleties associated with negative zero, which exists in ones'-complement systems.

Comment: Awesome answer. But I have to challenge you a bit, not to be a jerk but because this question is so close to what I'm working on. I'm guessing from your answer that you might not understand the CPU from a logic gate level. That definitely sounds like I'm arrogant about this, but that's not it at all. I find these things incredibly difficult actually. So, my question to you is, how many logic gates does it take to build an Adder? Say you're only building with NAND gates. Does this answer seem familiar or am I way off?

Comment: (Comment not taken as arrogant, don't worry.) It's been about 4 years since my college computer systems course so I don't remember exactly how AND/OR/NOT/XOR/etc is built up into latches/flip-flops/etc. That said, I'm not sure that your further questions are immediately relevant to teaching young kids about binary representation. Just to the binary arithmetic on paper and it's clear how two's complement simplifies things.

Comment: Right, good point. But it is relevant. Here's why. If you flood a kid with details about binary notation and two's compliment, they quickly loose interest. But when you present them with a problem, even if it's as complicated as "ok here's a machine that can do x and y, can you get it to add 7 to -5?" - if it sparks in their mind: "ok, the machine can only do this one thing, but maybe I can alter the way the input thing is represented..." I know this seems like a far stretch for a 9 year old, but it's really not. The smarter kids will lunge for this kind of problem.

Comment: @dvanaria: If you use a propagating carry, you'll need one AND and one XOR per bit-pair (so for 8-bit bytes, you'd need 16 gates, if you're using NAND-only, you'd probably land in the region of 24-48). I suspect a subtraction "gate" would be of roughly the same size. Of course, CPUs these days tend to operate on 32- or 64-bit quantitiers, so the savings are greater now.

Comment: Modern CPUs use carry-lookahead adders (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry-lookahead_adder) in order to increase speed. A simple ripple carry adder like @Vatine was talking about takes a longer because the carry has to propagate all the way to the end for the operation to finish, and in a carry lookahead adder the carry is propagated first (which can be done faster) and then fed into the adders.

Answer (score 3):

Write down a number line

-32768... -1, 0, 1, 2, ... 32767

Add moves to the right.  Subtract moves to the left.  Conceptually nice, but how can we represent the sign?

We can use "signed magnitude" where the sign and the value are separate.  This gets confusing because we have two parallel number lines with differing signs.

An alternative to "signed magnitude" is to encode each number as another number.

We can add an offset of 32768 to all the numbers.  The new range is the unsigned 0 to 65535.  Everything still works, right?  You just have a fixed bias value applied to all the numbers.  Add moves to the right.  Subtract moves to the left.  32768 can be decoded to 0.  0 can be decoded to -32768.

This works perfectly.  The "encoding" a number is simply adding a bias.  "Decoding" a number simply subtracts the bias.

Here's another encoding scheme.

Carry all the negative numbers over to the other side of the number line.

0, 1, 2, ..., 32767, -32768, ... -1

Addition still moves to the right.  Take any number (with one exception).  The number to the right of it is always larger.

The one exception is 32767.  The number to the right of it is "overflow".

Subtract still moves to the left.  Take any number (with one exception). The number to the left is always smaller.  The one exception is -32768.  The number on the left of it is "underflow".

The encoding and decoding are a little more involved.  0 to 32767 have a trivial encoding and  decoding: do nothing.  The numbers are encoded as themselves.  32768 to 65535, however, are encodings of negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Two's compliment is used to simplify addition and subtraction into one operation which can be performed by one hardware unit.  Instead of subtracting one number from another, in two's compliment arithmetic you add one number's inverse to another.  Back in the olden days, having a separate piece of hardware for subtracting numbers would have been a pretty big deal, so coming up with a system to perform subtraction and addition with a single unit was very useful.

You can find the inverse of any number in two's compliment by flipping the bits and adding one.  For instance, `-1` would be represented as follows in a four bit implementation:

```
 1: 0001
-1: 1110 + 1 = 1111
```

You can verify this by adding the two:

```
 0001 + 1111 = 10000
```

We're working with four bits, however, so the result is truncated.  We now have `0000`, or `0`.  We have added a number and its negative and gotten zero.  Hurray!

Now, for one final example, let's do 4 - 6.  4 is represented as `0100`.  6 is represented as `0110`.  To get -6, flip the bits and add one: `1001 + 1 = 1010`.  `0100 + 1010 = 1110`.  `1110` is a negative number (all numbers with a `1` in the most significant digit are negative in two's compliment).  To find out its absolute value, we flip the bits and add 1. `0001 + 1 = 0010`, or 2.  Therefore, the result of our addition is `-2`.  `4 - 6  -2`.  Our math checks out.

Congratulations.  You are now exactly as smart as a computer.

Answer (score 0):

Q1. How do computers represent negative numbers?

[2's compliment method!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Q2 . Why do computers represent negative numbers this way?

Here's how 2's compliment work:

For any x,

```
x + ~x   = all the bits set  
x + ~x   = 2^m - 1      (2^m = the range of numbers we opt)  
  -x     = ~x + 1 - 2^m (we can cancel out mod 2^m, which gives)  
  -x     = ~x + 1
```

As you can see, 2's compliment is logical and easy to implement and doesn't have corner cases and that is why it is preferred over other methods.
Lets consider [1's compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) , a method with corner cases I was talking about, in which 0 and -0 exist (all bits not set = 0, all bits set = -0) which translates to more operations to perform for the Hardware circuits, especially during operations with a number x and -0. [Wikipedia has nice examples on [Avoiding Negative Zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement#Avoiding_negative_zero), you can have a look at them]

I hope this explanation soothes the minds of your kids...