# Advantage of 2's complement over 1's complement?

Tags: binary, negative-number

What is the advantage of 2's complement over 1s' complement in negative number representation in binary number system? How does it affect the range of values stored in a certain bit representation of number in binary system?

Comment: I think this Wikipedia article should answer this question sufficiently: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations

Comment: It is not a question of advantage. The first step in two's complement IS one's complement. After that one is added to eliminate the presence of a positive zero and a negative zero. (You must eliminate a bit because you "bought" a bit to carry the sign -- and that eliminates TWO values from use in the bit width you are using.)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The primary advantage of two's complement over ones' complement is that two's complement only has one value for zero. Ones' complement has a "positive" zero and a "negative" zero.

Next, to add numbers using one's complement you have to first do binary addition, then add in an end-around carry value.

Two's complement has only one value for zero, and doesn't require carry values.

You also asked how the range of values stored are affected. Consider an eight-bit integer value, the following are your minimum and maximum values:

| Notation | Min | Max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Unsigned: | 0 | 255 |
| One's Comp: | -127 | +127 |
| Two's Comp: | -128 | +127 |

References:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: To generalize it: For N-bit, One's compliment can represent integers in range `−(2^(N−1)−1) to 2^(N−1)−1` and Two's compliment can represent integers in range `−2^(N−1) to 2^(N−1)−1`.

Answer (score 26):

The major advantages are:

1. In 1's there is a `-0` (`11111111`) and a `+0` (`00000000`), i.e two value for the same `0`. On the other hand, in 2's complement, there is only one value for `0` (`00000000`). This is because

   ```
   +0 --> 00000000
   ```

   and

   ```
    -0 --> 00000000 --> 11111111 + 1 --> 00000000
   ```
2. While doing arithmetic operations like addition or subtraction using 1's, we have to add an extra carry bit, i.e `1` to the result to get the correct answer, e.g.:

   ```
          +1(00000001)
        +
          -1(11111110)
        -----------------
        = (11111111)
   ```

but the correct answer is `0`. In order to get `0` we have to add a carry 
  bit `1` to the result (`11111111 + 1 = 00000000`).

In 2's complement, the result doesn't have to be modified:

```
               +1(00000001)
              +
               -1(11111111)
         -----------------
              = 1 00000000
```

Answer (score 7):

**Negative integers :** 
2's complement makes sense to be used for negative integers. 1's complement is just a computation technique which might be helpful to evaluate 2's complement. The real (defeated) rival of 2's complement was the sign-magnitude representation for negative integers.

**No overflow :** 1's complement has no special usage for negative integers. 2's complement makes sense because it can be used in natural addition and subtraction arithmetic without any need to change the bits. Providing that no overflow occurs, the sign bit of the result is just the right value. The bit number promotion in this notation is straight forward, for example, to promote an 8-bit signed integer to 16, we could simply repeat the sign bit of integer value in the high byte of it.

**Sign magnitude :** On the contrary, the sign-magnitude notation is just the way that human uses to represent negative integers. The bit number promotion and addition subtraction arithmetic is a bit mess with this notation.

Answer (score 3):

### Advantages of Two’s Complement #1

In Two’s Complement representation, the value zero is 
uniquely represented by having all bits set to zero:

**

### Advantages of Two’s Complement #2

**
When you perform an arithmetic operation (for example, 
addition, subtraction, multiplication, division) on two 
signed integers in Two’s Complement representation, you 
can use 
exactly the same method
as if you had two 
unsigned integers (that is, nonnegative integers with no sign 
bit) ...
EXCEPT
, you throw away the high carry (or the high 
borrow
for subtraction)

### **Advantages of Two’s Complement #3**

This property of Two’s Complement representation is so

### incredibly handy that virtually every general

purpose 
computer available today uses Two’s Complement.
Why? Because, with Two’s Complement, we don’t need 
special algorithms 
(and therefore extra circuitry) for 
arithmetic operations that involve negative values.

Answer (score 2):

Another major advantage of Two's complement over signed bit representation is 2's complement representation is easy to manipulate in hardware

Comment: Isn't this hen-egg problem though?  since the hardware would optimize whichever one was chosen...

Comment: @Pacerier, no it's not. It doesn't matter whether the hardware would optimize whichever one is chosen. It's the fact that the circuitry (system of logic gates connected together) required to build the hardware needed to optimize addition & subtraction on 1's complement numbers would be more complicated then the circuitry of the hardware needed to optimize addition & subtraction on 2's complement.

Comment: @user904542, Do you mean **all** electronic hardware? Hmm, what about new biocomputers?

Answer (score 1):

2s complement isn't for representing a negative number it's an inverse.

Means you can do A + B' (where B' is the 2s complement of B) to give A - B, means you can do everything with an adder and not need a substracter

Comment: Did you mean that its not two's compliment that represent negative number but 2's compliment are represented by negative number?

Comment: Nope 2s complement is the decimal equivalent of * -1. 2s complement of a negative number is positive as in the most significant bit is zero