# Is this an overflow arithmetic calculation?

Tags: overflow, integer-arithmetic

So when I read the book and it says that overflow can't occur when add different signs and subtraction of the same sign.
 But I have question when I do this: 185 - 122
I converted binary of 122 to 2s complement and did the addition, which is different signs:
185+(-122) and when I add them together, I got the sign bit overflow to 100111111. But if I cut off the MSB on the left, it is the correct answer. Is it an overflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't overflow - the overflow resulting from the addition of 2 `1's` in the MSB must just be discarded. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Converting_to_two.27s_complement_representation)

> To get the two's complement of a binary number, the bits are inverted, or "flipped", by using the bitwise NOT operation; the value of 1 is then added to the resulting value, ignoring the overflow which occurs when taking the two's complement of 0.

So in your example

```
185 10111001
122 01111010 -
```

Taking the 2's complement of 122 (One's complement +1)

```
01111010 => 10000110
```

Adding:

```
10111001 185
10000110 +(-122)
--------
00111111 (63)
```

=63

The `overflow` is ignored.

There are however rules for detecting overflow after doing the 2's complement :

- If the sum of two positive numbers results in a negative result
- If the sum of two negative numbers results a positive result

Comment: @Rozen - there are some further answers here http://stackoverflow.com/q/6853524/314291 on why CPU's / ALU's use 2's complement internally. Obviously, as end users, we would just e.g. use  `SUB` to subtract on an Intel)