# How does Java calculate negative numbers?

Tags: java, bit

I use the `~` operation for bit manipulation, and I'm just wondering how Java calculates the negative number?

I checked the Java documentation:

> "The unary bitwise complement operator "~" inverts a bit pattern; it can be applied to any of the integral types, making every "0" a "1" and every "1" a "0". For example, a byte contains 8 bits; applying this operator to a value whose bit pattern is "00000000" would change its pattern to "11111111"."

So if `int a = 60 (0011 1100)`, then `int c = ~a (1100 0011)`.

The question is, how Java calculate negative numbers so that `1100 0011 = -61`? The only way `1100 0011` is calculated `-61` is

1. the highest bit is the sign bit.
2. `-2^6 + 2^1 + 2^0 = -61`.

But this make no sense to me.

Comment: You're on the right track with the highest bit being the sign bit.  Please see [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement).

Comment: signed bit is used for double and float which means that you have 0.0 and -0.0, integers are not done this way and `char` is unsigned.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The assumption that the highest bit is a simple *sign bit* is **wrong**. Java, as well as most modern programming languages (and hardware architectures) use the so-called [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%27s_complement) representation for numbers. (The bit itself, coincidentally, does indicate the sign, but not in the way you would expect it to, i.e. 150 and -150 have more differences than just the sign bit in their representation.)

This representation might seem like an odd choice at first, but it actually makes operations such as adding a positive number to a negative number (or variations of this) automagically work, without making the processor have to check for special cases.

According to [the relevant Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%27s_complement):

> The system is useful in simplifying the implementation of arithmetic on computer hardware. Adding 0011 (3) to 1111 (−1) at first seems to give the incorrect answer of 10010. However, the hardware can simply ignore the left-most bit to give the correct answer of 0010 (2). Overflow checks still must exist to catch operations such as summing 0100 and 0100.
>   The system therefore allows addition of negative operands without a subtraction circuit and a circuit that detects the sign of a number. Moreover, that addition circuit can also perform subtraction by taking the two's complement of a number (see below), which only requires an additional cycle or its own adder circuit. To perform this, the circuit merely pretends an extra left-most bit of 1 exists.

**[See this related answer for an even more in-depth explanation with lots of nice, easy to understand examples.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125304/why-is-twos-complement-used-to-represent-negative-numbers/1125317#1125317)**

Answer (score 4):

Java's [primitive numeral data types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) - `int`, `long`, `byte`, and `short` are represented in [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2%27s_complement).  What this means:

- The *highest* value is the result of all bits set to 1, save for the MSB.

  - Example:  `0111 1111 = 127`
- The MSB being set to 1 and all other bits set to 0 is the *lowest* value.

  - Example:  `1000 0000 = -128`

The only negative value here is the MSB, so if we break it down into this representation, we'll arrive at -61:

```
|-128 | 64 | 32 | 16 | 8 | 4 | 2 | 1 |
|  1  |  1 | 0  |  0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

-128 + 64 + 2 + 1 = -61.
```

Comment: In case anyone's wondering: MSB = Most Significant Bit = highest-order place of a binary integer ≃ most significant digit of a decimal integer