# How represent -128 in binary for a byte?

Tags: binary

In order to avoid representing 0 in two different ways when representing signed integers in bytes such as

```
10000000
```

and

```
00000000
```

one can say, by convention, that `10000000` = -128. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the twos complement representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously there are different possible representations, including the one you mentioned which has two different numbers for 0.

Two's complement is the only representation I know of that's used in computers, and for that one your assumption is correct. In the datatype sometimes known as `signed char`, binary `10000000` is indeed -128. See:

- [What is “2's Complement”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement)
- [Why is two's complement used to represent negative numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125304/why-is-twos-complement-used-to-represent-negative-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not quite by convention - it is a formula. By the same formula -1 will be 11111111.

Read here for details http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement