# What is the logic of one\two complement representation of binary numers

Tags: binary, twos-complement, representation, ones-complement

I am trying to understand the logic behind the  arithmetic of one\two complement.   Why I can sum\subtract numbers with this method and get the right answer, and why all the issue of "carry" works in this two method as it works?
Someone could help?

Comment: Number theory. Arithmetic in ℤ/2ⁿℤ, the congruence classes of integers modulo 2ⁿ.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is two's complement used to represent negative numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125304/why-is-twos-complement-used-to-represent-negative-numbers)