# why C, C++, Java does not use one complement?

Tags: java, c++, c, complement

I heard C, C++, Java uses two complements for binary representation. Why not use 1 complement? Is there any advantage to use 2 complement over 1 complement?

Comment: If this is homework--which is ok--please tag it that way so we can help you with hints and guidance instead of answers

Comment: who said that this is homework?

Comment: Java uses 2's complement, but in C and C++ the representation of the signed integer types is implementation defined.

Comment: Seems like a legitimate non-homework question

Comment: "C, C++, [...] uses two complements" is wrong. 2's complement is just much more common. C and C++ also allow 1's complement and sign+magnitude. It depends on the machine and if you want to write truly portable code you have to know this.

Comment: @tsubasa: I said *if this is homework*--I didn't say it was or retag

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Working with two's complement signed integers is a lot cleaner. You can basically add signed values as if they were unsigned and have things work as you might expect, rather than having to explicitly deal with an additional carry addition. It is also easier to check if a value is 0, because two's complement only contains one 0 value, whereas one's complement allows one to define both a positive and a negative zero.

As for the additional carry addition, think about adding a positive number to a smallish negative number. Because of the one's complement representation, the smallish negative number will actually be fairly large when viewed as an unsigned quantity. Adding the two together might lead to an overflow with a carry bit. Unlike unsigned addition, this doesn't necessarily mean that the value is too large to represent in the one's complement number, just that the representation temporarily exceeded the number of bits available. To compensate for this, you add the carry bit back in after adding the two one's complement numbers together.

Comment: Can you give me an example for your saying "rather than having to explicitly deal with an additional carry addition."? Thanks.

Comment: The wikipedia article can probably explain better than I can, but I added a small paragraph on it to my answer too.

Answer (score 7):

The internal representation of numbers is not part of any of those languages, it's a feature of the architecture of the machine itself.  Most implementations use 2's complement because it makes addition and subtraction the same binary operation (signed and unsigned operations are identical).

Comment: Strictly speaking, a language could go out of its way to use ones' complement if it really wanted to. It would be slow, but it could do it :)

Comment: Very good point - usually those languages just expose what's underlying (though bdonlan has a point)

Comment: @Carl - actually, for Java the representation of integers **is** part of the language specification.

Comment: I guess that makes sense, since Java specifies the machine it runs on, too (the JVM).

Answer (score 2):

Is this a homework question?  If so, think of how you would represent 0 in a 1's complement system.

Comment: Carl, you have more than enough rep to fix a spelling mistake.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is different for different languages.

In the case of C, you could *in theory* implement the language on a 1's complement machine ... if you could still find a working 1's complement machine to run your programs!  Using 1's complement would introduce portability issues, but that's the norm for C.  I'm not sure what the deal is for C++, but I wouldn't be surprised if it is the same.

In the case of Java, the language specification sets out precise sizes and representations for the primitive types, and precise behaviour for the arithmetic operators.  This is done to eliminate the portability issues that arise when you make these things implementation specific.  The Java designers specified 2's complement arithmetic because all modern CPU architectures implement 2's complement and not 1's complement integers.

For reasons why modern hardware implements 2's complement and not 1's complement, take a look at (for example) the Wikipedia pages on the subject.  See if you can figure out the implications of the alternatives.

Comment: The C and C++ standards both make specific allowance for signed integers being one's complement or even sign-and-magnitude, even though AFAIK no one has *ever* implemented either language on such a machine (as best I can tell, no such CPU has been manufactured since the 1970s).

Answer (score 1):

At least C and C++ offer 1's complement negation (which is the same as bitwise negation) via the language's `~` operator. Most processors - and all modern ones - use 2's complement representation for a couple reasons:

- Adding positive and negative numbers is the same as adding unsigned integers
- No "wasted" values due to two representations of 0 (+0 and -0)

**Edit:** The [draft of C++0x](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/SC22-N-4411.pdf) does not specify whether signed integer types are 1's complement or 2's complement, which means it's highly unlikely that earlier versions of C and C++ did specify it. What you have observed is *implementation-defined behavior*, which is 2's complement on at least modern processors for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all existing CPU hardware uses two's complement, so it makes sense that most programming languages do, too.

C and C++ support one's complement, if the hardware provides it.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with zero and rounding. If you use 1st complement, you can end up have two zeros. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/2s-complement-defined) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Sign-magnitude representation would be much better for numeric code.  The lack of symmetry is a real problem with 2's complement and also precludes a lot of useful (numeric orientated) bit-hacks. 2's complement also introduces trick situations where an arithmetic operation may not give you the result you think it might. So you must be mindful with regards to division, shifting and negation.