# Use (Python) Gstreamer to decode audio (to PCM data)

Tags: python, audio, decode, gstreamer, pcm

I'm writing an application that uses the Python Gstreamer bindings to play audio, but I'm now trying to also just decode audio -- that is, I'd like to read data using a [`decodebin`](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-components-decodebin.html) and receive a raw PCM buffer. Specifically, I want to read chunks of the file incrementally rather than reading the whole file into memory.

Some specific questions: How can I accomplish this with Gstreamer? With pygst specifically? Is there a particular "sink" element I need to use to read data from the stream? Is there a preferred way to read data from a [pygst `Buffer` object](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-reference/class-gstbuffer.html)? How do I go about controlling the rate at which I consume data (rather than just entering a "main loop")?

Comment: More future reference: this is the solution I came up with (with elmarco's help), which might be useful in other projects as well. http://github.com/sampsyo/pylastfp/blob/master/lastfp/gstdec.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the data back in your application, the recommended way is [appsink](http://gstreamer.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/gst-plugins-base-libs-appsink.html).

Based on a simple audio player like [this one](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/src-sink-pad.html) (and replace the oggdemux/vorbisdec by decodebin & capsfilter with caps = "audio/x-raw-int"), change autoaudiosink to appsink, and connect ["new-buffer"](http://www.gstreamer.net/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-appsink.html#GstAppSink-new-buffer) signal to a python function + set "emit-signals" to True. The function will receive decoded chunks of PCM/int data. The rate of the decoding will depend on the rate at which you can decode and consume. Since the new-buffer signal is in the Gstreamer thread context, you could just sleep/wait in that function to control or slow down the decoding speed.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about appsink. This helps a lot!

Comment: One additional note (for future reference) after trying this: it seems that you need to set the "sync" property of the appsink to false in order to get data as quickly as possible. Otherwise, you'll consume data in real time.

Comment: One detail: the Python bindings for appsink don't bind gst_appsink_pull_buffer() method; instead you need to call appsink.emit('pull-buffer').