# PCM data in array from flac file

Tags: python, c, pcm, flac

I have a flac file and I need to analize its waveform, so I need to have the pcm data in an array. Is there some library which does this for me without converting the file with commandline tools? I can use both Python and C.

Comment: The most common answer to this if you're using linux is "Use Gstreamer". [See this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507746/use-python-gstreamer-to-decode-audio-to-pcm-data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use libFLAC to decode. http://flac.sourceforge.net/