# I can't store my data as an array

Tags: python

I'm trying to read data from a .wav file and store it in an array as such:

```
out = struct.unpack_from("%dh" % num_frames * num_channels, frames)
self.data = array(out)
```

When I try this I get the error:

```
self.data = array(out)
TypeError: must be char, not tuple
```

What's causing this error? Are all the values in `out` not the same type? Shouldn't they all be negative or positive integers?

Comment: if you print `out`, what do you get?

Comment: Print `out` and check what your result is?

Comment: Oh I tried that but it's an absolutely massive list of negative and positive integers. It's not feasible to go through every item. I checked the first 10 and they were integers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the [array class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), the constructor takes two arguments, the first being a character representing a type code.

So you want

```
from array import array
out = <...>
self.data = array('b', out)
```

Or one of the other type codes listed in the docs instead of `'b'`.

Or you can use [numpy.array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html), in which case your code should work as-is:

```
from numpy import array
out = <...>
self.data = array(out)
```

Comment: It worked. I used `'h'` instead of `'b'`. It worked previously without using the first argument as outlined in the top rated answer of this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063284/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-read-wav-files-using-python-summary?lq=1

Comment: Hmm, maybe they are talking about `numpy.array`? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html

Comment: Ah, that's what it was! Everything is back to normal now. Phew.