# how to get wav samples from a wav file?

Tags: python, wav

I want to know how to get samples out of a .wav file in order to perform windowed join of two .wav files.

Can any one please tell how to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [wave](http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html?highlight=wav#module-wave) module of the standard library is the key: after of course `import wave` at the top of your code, `wave.open('the.wav', 'r')` returns a "wave read" object from which you can read frames with the `.readframes` method, which returns a string of bytes which are the samples... in whatever format the wave file has them (you can determine the two parameters relevant to decomposing frames into samples with the `.getnchannels` method for the number of channels, and `.getsampwidth` for the number of bytes per sample).

The best way to turn the string of bytes into a sequence of numeric values is with the `array` module, and a type of (respectively) `'B'`, `'H'`, `'L'` for 1, 2, 4 bytes per sample (on a 32-bit build of Python; you can use the `itemsize` value of your array object to double-check this).  If you have different sample widths than `array` can provide you, you'll need to slice up the byte string (padding each little slice appropriately with bytes worth 0) and use the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html?highlight=struct#module-struct) module instead (but that's clunkier and slower, so use `array` instead if you can).

Comment: when i try .getsamplewidth it gave me a value 2 meaning that 2 bytes..
when i try .readframes(1) should return 1 frame then it returned for me such as " /x03/x16 " 
which i guess is 2 bytes,so does it means that 1 frame has only 1 sample..
what is use getnchannels ?? 
i want to take samples from each frame separetely and represent them in intergers,how can i ??

Comment: @kaki, in each frame, there is the first sample from each channel, then the second sample from each channel, then so on.  So unless your sound is mono i.e. just 1 channel you have to decide what to do ith the channels (skip all but one, average them, whatever).  Say it's 1 channel (mono), simplest, then `x = array.array('h', w.getframes(1))` gives you in `x` an array with all the samples of the first frame (next one, if in a loop) as integers, just as you say you want (`h`, not `H`: they're signed). If stereo, 2 channels, even indices of `x` have e.g. left channel samples.  Little-endian btw.

Comment: BTW, the format docs at https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/ do not use the concept of "frames" but rather "chunks" and "subchunks", but in the end it comes to much the same thing of course;-).

Comment: @kaki, you're welcome -- but do consider accepting the answer that has helped you (by clicking on the checkmark outline on the Q's left), as that is really fundamental SO etiquette!

Comment: @AlexMartelli Sorry for grave digging, but I'm trying to use .readframes(1) and I need it to split the two samples into two separate variables (basically put the first left sample in variable X, and the first right sample into variable Y), but I don't have a clue how to do this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`wave`](http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html) module. First you should read the metadata, such us sample size or the number of channels. Using the `readframes()` method, you can read samples, but only as a byte string. Based on the sample format, you have to convert them to samples using [`struct.unpack()`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#struct.unpack).

Alternatively, if you want the samples as an array of floating-point numbers, you can use SciPy's [`io.wavfile`](http://www.scipy.org/doc/api_docs/SciPy.io.wavfile.html) module.

Comment: can u tell me how to get sample as an array of floatinf point numbers without using scipy

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function to read samples from a wave file (tested with mono & stereo):

```
def read_samples(wave_file, nb_frames):
    frame_data = wave_file.readframes(nb_frames)
    if frame_data:
        sample_width = wave_file.getsampwidth()
        nb_samples = len(frame_data) // sample_width
        format = {1:"%db", 2:"<%dh", 4:"<%dl"}[sample_width] % nb_samples
        return struct.unpack(format, frame_data)
    else:
        return ()
```

And here's the full script that does windowed mixing or concatenating of multiple `.wav` files.  All input files need to have the same params (# of channels and sample width).

```
import argparse
import itertools
import struct
import sys
import wave

def _struct_format(sample_width, nb_samples):
    return {1:"%db", 2:"<%dh", 4:"<%dl"}[sample_width] % nb_samples

def _mix_samples(samples):
    return sum(samples)//len(samples)

def read_samples(wave_file, nb_frames):
    frame_data = wave_file.readframes(nb_frames)
    if frame_data:
        sample_width = wave_file.getsampwidth()
        nb_samples = len(frame_data) // sample_width
        format = _struct_format(sample_width, nb_samples)
        return struct.unpack(format, frame_data)
    else:
        return ()

def write_samples(wave_file, samples, sample_width):
    format = _struct_format(sample_width, len(samples))
    frame_data = struct.pack(format, *samples)
    wave_file.writeframes(frame_data)

def compatible_input_wave_files(input_wave_files):
    nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, nframes, comptype, compname = input_wave_files[0].getparams()
    for input_wave_file in input_wave_files[1:]:
        nc,sw,fr,nf,ct,cn = input_wave_file.getparams()
        if (nc,sw,fr,ct,cn) != (nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, comptype, compname):
            return False
    return True

def mix_wave_files(output_wave_file, input_wave_files, buffer_size):
    output_wave_file.setparams(input_wave_files[0].getparams())
    sampwidth = input_wave_files[0].getsampwidth()
    max_nb_frames = max([input_wave_file.getnframes() for input_wave_file in input_wave_files])
    for frame_window in xrange(max_nb_frames // buffer_size + 1):
        all_samples = [read_samples(wave_file, buffer_size) for wave_file in input_wave_files]
        mixed_samples = [_mix_samples(samples) for samples in itertools.izip_longest(*all_samples, fillvalue=0)]
        write_samples(output_wave_file, mixed_samples, sampwidth)

def concatenate_wave_files(output_wave_file, input_wave_files, buffer_size):
    output_wave_file.setparams(input_wave_files[0].getparams())
    sampwidth = input_wave_files[0].getsampwidth()
    for input_wave_file in input_wave_files:
        nb_frames = input_wave_file.getnframes()
        for frame_window in xrange(nb_frames // buffer_size + 1):
            samples = read_samples(input_wave_file, buffer_size)
            if samples:
                write_samples(output_wave_file, samples, sampwidth)

def argument_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Mix or concatenate multiple .wav files')
    parser.add_argument('command', choices = ("mix", "concat"), help='command')
    parser.add_argument('output_file', help='ouput .wav file')
    parser.add_argument('input_files', metavar="input_file", help='input .wav files', nargs="+")
    parser.add_argument('--buffer_size', type=int, help='nb of frames to read per iteration', default=1000)
    return parser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = argument_parser().parse_args()

    input_wave_files = [wave.open(name,"rb") for name in args.input_files]
    if not compatible_input_wave_files(input_wave_files):
        print "ERROR: mixed wave files must have the same params."
        sys.exit(2)

    output_wave_file = wave.open(args.output_file, "wb")
    if args.command == "mix":
        mix_wave_files(output_wave_file, input_wave_files, args.buffer_size)
    elif args.command == "concat":
        concatenate_wave_files(output_wave_file, input_wave_files, args.buffer_size)

    output_wave_file.close()
    for input_wave_file in input_wave_files:
        input_wave_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the samples (for example with the wave module, more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26716031/3244382)) you may want to have the values scales between -1 and 1 (this is the convention for audio signals).

In this case, you can add:

```
# scale to -1.0 -- 1.0
max_nb_bit = float(2**(nb_bits-1))  
samples = signal_int / (max_nb_bit + 1.0)
```

with `nb_bits` the bit depth and `signal_int` the integers values.