# How can MATLAB function wavread() be implemented in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, audio

In Matlab:

```
[s, fs] = wavread(file);
```

Since the value of each element in s is between -1 and 1, so we import scikits.audiolab using its wavread function.

```
from scikits.audiolab import wavread
s, fs, enc = wavread(filename)
```

But when I red the same input wav file, the value of s in Matlab and Python were totally different. How could I get the same output of s as in MATLAB?

p.s. The wav file is simple 16-bit mono channel file sampled in 44100Hz.

Comment: Well, what is the datatype of `s`, i.e., `type(s)`? How about if you compare using the `'native'` option in Matlab's `wavread`?

Answer (score 4):

The Matlab `wavread()` function returns normalised data as default, i.e. it scales all the data to the range -1 to +1. If your audio file is in 16-bit format then the raw data values will be in the range -32768 to +32767, which should match the range returned by `scikits.audiolab.wavread()`.

To normalise this data to within the range -1 to +1 all you need to do is divide the data array by the value with the maximum magnitude (using the [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) module in this case):

```
from scikits.audiolab import wavread
import numpy

s, fs, enc = wavread(filename)  # s in range -32768 to +32767
s = numpy.array(s)
s = s / max(abs(s))             # s in range -1 to +1
```

Note that you can also use the `'native'` option with the Matlab function to return un-normalised data values, as suggested by horchler in his comment.

```
[s, fs] = wavread(file, 'native');
```

Comment: I can no longer test things in MATLAB, but I think it does not scale values quite as you say. I think it scales max and min integer values (rather than max and min sampled values) to -1 and +1, respectively. So rather than dividing by max(abs(s)), you might instead divide by (2**15 - 1) for 16-bit samples. I'm not yet sure how to look up the max normalizing value dynamically in case of encountering other bit-depths. This is particularly important if you're loading different files and need the levels to be comparable.

Comment: You can get the maximum value of a data type by `numpy.iinfo(s).max`.

Comment: Note: for some applications it seems more common to divide by 2^(n_bits - 1) instead of the max value. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060628/reading-wav-files-in-python