# looking for reading audio wave values in python

Tags: python, audio

I'm trying to read and manipulate audio file , 
how to read and manipulate the waves value of a wave file using python?

Comment: Does `import wave` not work for you? https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html

Comment: Mr.  Kmeixner , 
I looking for sound steganography , using python :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [SciPy libraries](http://www.scipy.org/) have great resources for this:

> Writing and Reading:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.io import wavfile

fs = 44.1e3
t = np.arange(0, 1.0, 1.0/fs)

f1 = 440
f2 = 600

x = 0.5*np.sin(2*np.pi*f1*t) + 0.5*np.sin(2*np.pi*f2*t)

fname = 'output.wav'
wavfile.write( fname, fs, x )


fs, data = wavfile.read( fname )

print fs, data[:10]
```

> Documentation: 
>   http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/io.html#module-scipy.io.wavfile

- **Reading:** http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html#scipy.io.wavfile.read
- **Writing:** http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html#scipy.io.wavfile.write

This question has been asked before: [Reading *.wav files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060628/how-to-read-wav-file-in-python)

Comment: feel free to accept this answer if you think it properly answers your question.