# align audio files that start and end at different times

Tags: python, audio

I have audio recordings that starts and ends at different times.

```
audio 1: -----t1--------------------------s1->time
audio 2: ---------t2----s2------------------->time
audio 3: ------------------------t3-------s3->time
```

audio 1 is the longest and it overlaps with both audio 2 and 3. 
audio 2, and audio 3 are short segments but they do not overlap at all. 
Is there a python library that does this?

Comment: What do you mean by start and end ? Do you want to read the audio files from a point that is nit the beginning?

Comment: those are recordings of the same event, some started before others. some ended earlier. so its kind of finding the offsets. @sandoval31

Answer (score 0):

You could first use a python library to **read the audio file** (numpy or scipy for instance, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26716031/3244382).

Then you have to **determine t and s for each file**. If the files are not too noisy a simple threshold on the audio signal could be sufficient. A little bit more sophisticated approach would be to compute the **RMS energy** or the **envelope** (that average the signal), and use a threshold on it.

Once you know **s** and **t**, you could write a new audio file from this boundaries with the same audio library.