# How do I find the discrete time fuunction of a wav file?

Tags: python, audio, input, signals, windowing

I want to apply a blackman hanning window to an audio signal (wav file). For this I need to find the discrete time signal of the wav file, because

xw(n) = x(n) * w(l).

But I have only managed to read the wavfile using scipy.io.wavfile.read. 
Which function will allow me find the x(n) of my wav file?

```
import winsound
import numpy 
winsound.PlaySound ("cat_got_tongue.wav",winsound.SND_FILENAME)
import scipy.io.wavfile
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rate, data = scipy.io.wavfile.read ("cat_got_tongue.wav")
window = numpy.blackman(256)
```

Comment: Please cheeck, C:\python3\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\wavfile.py:273

Comment: with scipy, we can read some wave file type. Please check your wave file type

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5281240/11343720

Comment: Per King Stone, possible duplicate of [Reading \*.wav files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060628/reading-wav-files-in-python)