# I try to read a sound, but the result is something like that \x00?\x00

Tags: python, numpy, wave

I'm trying to read an audio file, and then process it and get its energy, frequency .... But when I read it, I know how to translate it into the format in which it is found.

```
import numpy as np

import wave



import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import scipy.integrate as integrate



wav_file = wave.open('Alarm01.wav', 'r')


nchannels,sampwidth,framerate,nframes,comptype,compname = wav_file.getparams()


data = wav_file.readframes(nframes)

wav_file.close()

data
Out[100]: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\............
```

Comment: *"I know how to translate it "*  - did you mean you *don't* know how to translate it?

Comment: its just binary string you are reading, go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060628/reading-wav-files-in-python to read more.