# Wav audio level is too large

Tags: python-3.x, audio, normalization, wav, librosa

I have a mono wav file for a 'glass breaking' sound. When I graphically display it's levels in python using librosa library, it shows very large range of amplitudes, between +/ 20000 instead of +/- 1. When I open same wav file with Audacity, the levels are between +/- 1.

My question is what generates this difference in displayed amplitude levels and how can I correct it in Python? MinMax scaling will distort the sound and I want to avoid it if possible.

The code is:

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
fs1, glass_break_data = wavfile.read('test_break_glass_normalized.wav')

%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import librosa.display

sr=44100
x = glass_break_data.astype('float')

plt.figure(figsize=(14, 5))
librosa.display.waveplot(x, sr=sr)
```

These are the images from the notebook and Audacity:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

WAV usually uses integer values to represent individual samples, not floats. So what you see in the `librosa` plot is accurate for a 16 bit/sample audio file.

Programs like [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) show the format, including bit depth per sample in their info dialog, so you can easily check.
Another way to check the format might be using [soxi](http://sox.sourceforge.net/soxi.html) or [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org).

Audacity normalizes everything to floats in the range of -1 to 1—it does not show you the original format.

The same is true for `librosa.load()`—it also normalizes to `[-1,1]`. `wavfile.read()` on the other hand, does not normalize. For more info on ways to read WAV audio, please see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26716031/942774).

Answer (score 1):

If you use `librosa.load` instead of `wavfile.read` it will normalize the range to -1, 1

```
glass_break_data, fs1 = librosa.load('test_break_glass_normalized.wav')
```