# Any way to open measurement data recorded as WAV to readable numbers?

Tags: python, wav, labview

so I'm currently dealing with a fatigue test machine that perform cyclic loading on a specimen. The machine's software is made using LabView and the measurement data output is a WAV file since cyclic loading is basically just a time series of force amplitude. I've dealt with machines outputting .DAT and such but this is the first time I've dealt with WAV file and honestly I have no idea how to process this WAV file into readable series of numbers representing time and force.

So, does anyone know any program that can process it? Or if possible maybe do it with Python, since I'm quite familiar with it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wave module maybe https://docs.python.org/3/library/wave.html See also *"Think DSP"* - an excellent free book https://greenteapress.com/wp/think-dsp/

Comment: WAV is a format for audio data, but I assume you don't want to listen to it. What processing do you want to do and what language would you prefer to do it in?

Comment: @nekomatic Yeah, I don't want to listen to it. I just want to be able to extract the time-amplitude values of the signal and filter it so that I can use it to test and validate our current fatigue life simulation method. I would be able to do it in Python.

Comment: It looks as if [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2060628/244470) should sort you out, so I've voted that this is a duplicate of that; however if nothing there works for you feel free to update this one with more detail (e.g. any error messages you got, maybe a hex dump of the beginning of one of your files).

Comment: Alright, I'll do whatever I can in my capabilities first.