# How does bitshifting work in Java?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I have this statement:

> Assume the bit value of byte `x` is 00101011. what is the result of `x>>2`?

How can I program it and can someone explain me what is doing?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Firstly, you can *not* shift a `byte` in java, you can only shift an `int` or a `long`.  So the `byte` will undergo promotion first, e.g.

`00101011` -> `00000000000000000000000000101011`

or

`11010100` -> `11111111111111111111111111010100`

Now, `x >> N` means (if you view it as a string of binary digits):

- The rightmost N bits are discarded
- The leftmost bit is replicated as many times as necessary to pad the result to the original size (32 or 64 bits), e.g.

`00000000000000000000000000101011 >> 2` -> `00000000000000000000000000001010`

`11111111111111111111111111010100 >> 2` -> `11111111111111111111111111110101`

Comment: Would 11010100 be considered a negative number since it's left most bit is 1? \

Comment: @Pha3drus, yes, assuming the number is stored in 2's complement. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement.

Comment: I tried shifting int in java using:
@Test
    public void testBinaryString() {
        int n = 4;
        int v = n >> 1;
        System.out.println("v = " + v + ", n = " + n);
    }

But I get output: v = 2, n = 4. Wondering why it does not change n to 2?

Comment: Help. I am trying to get the 32nd bit of an int and get bad behaviour. when I mask that bit and shift it to first pos, I get -1 instead of 1.

Answer (score 63):

[image: Shift Operators]

The binary 32 bits for `00101011` is

`00000000 00000000 00000000 00101011`, and the result is:

```
  00000000 00000000 00000000 00101011   >> 2(times)
 \\                                 \\
  00000000 00000000 00000000 00001010
```

Shifts the bits of 43 to right by distance 2; fills with highest(sign) bit on the left side.

Result is 00001010 with decimal value 10.

```
00001010
    8+2 = 10
```

Answer (score 15):

When you shift right 2 bits you drop the 2 least significant bits.  So:

```
x = 00101011

x >> 2

// now (notice the 2 new 0's on the left of the byte)
x = 00001010
```

This is essentially the same thing as dividing an int by 2, 2 times.

**In Java**

```
byte b = (byte) 16;
b = b >> 2;
// prints 4
System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: Each right shift is divide by 2, so two right shifts is divide by 4.

Comment: Exactly. Or, in math speek: n >> m -> n / (2^m)

Comment: @delnan, yup, but that looks scary.

Comment: Might be a little clearer if you show the padding 0s to the left after the bitshift.

Comment: You cannot do bitwise shift operations on `byte` data type in Java programming language.

Comment: For Java, I get an error: `incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte` when doing this in terminal.

Answer (score 12):

These examples cover the three types of shifts applied to both a positive and a negative number:

```
// Signed left shift on 626348975
00100101010101010101001110101111 is   626348975
01001010101010101010011101011110 is  1252697950 after << 1
10010101010101010100111010111100 is -1789571396 after << 2
00101010101010101001110101111000 is   715824504 after << 3

// Signed left shift on -552270512
11011111000101010000010101010000 is  -552270512
10111110001010100000101010100000 is -1104541024 after << 1
01111100010101000001010101000000 is  2085885248 after << 2
11111000101010000010101010000000 is  -123196800 after << 3


// Signed right shift on 626348975
00100101010101010101001110101111 is   626348975
00010010101010101010100111010111 is   313174487 after >> 1
00001001010101010101010011101011 is   156587243 after >> 2
00000100101010101010101001110101 is    78293621 after >> 3

// Signed right shift on -552270512
11011111000101010000010101010000 is  -552270512
11101111100010101000001010101000 is  -276135256 after >> 1
11110111110001010100000101010100 is  -138067628 after >> 2
11111011111000101010000010101010 is   -69033814 after >> 3


// Unsigned right shift on 626348975
00100101010101010101001110101111 is   626348975
00010010101010101010100111010111 is   313174487 after >>> 1
00001001010101010101010011101011 is   156587243 after >>> 2
00000100101010101010101001110101 is    78293621 after >>> 3

// Unsigned right shift on -552270512
11011111000101010000010101010000 is  -552270512
01101111100010101000001010101000 is  1871348392 after >>> 1
00110111110001010100000101010100 is   935674196 after >>> 2
00011011111000101010000010101010 is   467837098 after >>> 3
```

Answer (score 5):

`>>` is the Arithmetic Right Shift operator. All of the bits in the first operand are shifted the number of places indicated by the second operand. The leftmost bits in the result are set to the same value as the leftmost bit in the original number. (This is so that negative numbers remain negative.)

Here's your specific case:

```
00101011
  001010 <-- Shifted twice to the right (rightmost bits dropped)
00001010 <-- Leftmost bits filled with 0s (to match leftmost bit in original number)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Shift {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Byte b = Byte.parseByte("00101011",2);
  System.out.println(b);
  byte val = b.byteValue();
  Byte shifted = new Byte((byte) (val >> 2));
  System.out.println(shifted);

  // often overloked  are the methods of Integer

  int i = Integer.parseInt("00101011",2);
  System.out.println( Integer.toBinaryString(i));
  i >>= 2;
  System.out.println( Integer.toBinaryString(i));
 }
}
```

Output:

```
43
10
101011
1010
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't write binary literals like `00101011` in Java so you can write it in hexadecimal instead:

```
byte x = 0x2b;
```

To calculate the result of `x >> 2` you can then just write exactly that and print the result.

```
System.out.println(x >> 2);
```

Comment: whats about Byte.parseByte("00101011",2); ?

Comment: Is this calculated at compile time or does it result in a method call at runtime?

Comment: Java 7 should be adding binary literals, e.g.: `0b00101011`

Comment: @Alan Kreuger: That's excellent news. :) Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2):

```
byte x = 51; //00101011
byte y = (byte) (x >> 2); //00001010 aka Base(10) 10
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use e.g. this API if you would like to see bitString presentation of your numbers. [Uncommons Math](http://maths.uncommons.org/api/org/uncommons/maths/binary/package-summary.html)

Example (in jruby)

```
bitString = org.uncommons.maths.binary.BitString.new(java.math.BigInteger.new("12").toString(2))
bitString.setBit(1, true)
bitString.toNumber => 14
```

**edit**: Changed api link and add a little example

Comment: The URL mentioned above is dead. Please remove/edit it to point to right web page.

Comment: Updated link. I'm not sure if this answers that changed question anymore though ..

Comment: You saved HTTP request with a dead URL!

Answer (score 0):

00101011 = 43 in decimal

```
class test {    
    public static void main(String[] args){
       int a= 43;       
       String b= Integer.toBinaryString(a >> 2);        
       System.out.println(b);
    }   
}
```

Output:

101011 becomes 1010

Comment: Can you please clarify what distinguishes this answer from the others posted here?