# How to use bitshifting in Java

Tags: java, binary, bit-manipulation, packets

I am trying to construct an IP header.

An IP header has the following fields: Version, IHL, DSCP etc. I would like to populate a Byte Array such that I can store the information in bytes.

Where I get confused however is that the Version field is only 4 bits wide. IHL is also only 4 bits wide. How do I fit the values of both of those fields to be represented as a byte? Do I need to do bitshifting?

E.g. Version = 4, IHL = 5. I would need to create a byte that would equal 0100 0101 = 45h or 69 decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(byte) (4 << 4) | 5
```

This shifts the value 4 to the left, then sets lower 4 bits to the value 5.

1. `00000100` A value (`4`)
2. `01000000` After shifting left 4 bits (`<< 4`)
3. `00000101` Another value (`5`)
4. `01000101` The result of a bitwise OR (`|`) of #2 and #3

Because the operands are `int` types (and even if they were `byte` values, they'd be promoted to `int` when operators like `|` act on them), the final result needs a cast to be stored in a `byte`.

If you are using `byte` values as operands in any bitwise operations, the implicit conversion to `int` can cause unexpected results. If you want to treat a `byte` as if it were unsigned in that conversion, use a bitwise AND (`&`):

```
byte b = -128; // The byte value 0x80, -128d
int uint8 = b & 0xFF; // The int value 0x00000080, 128d
int i = b; // The int value 0xFFFFFF80, -128d
int uintr = (b & 0xFF) | 0x04; // 0x00000084
int sintr = b | 0x04; // 0xFFFFFF84
```

Comment: `byte Version = 5; byte IHL = 4; byte b = (Version << 4) + IHL;` compiles fine, no casting needed

Comment: Thanks @Erickson - great answer.

Comment: Probably would be best with just the top portion, before introducing ints into the answer

Comment: Then why can I compile it without errors, just using bytes and without casting?

Comment: What compiler should I be using for testing things like this?  `byte b = (((byte)5) << 4) + ((byte)4); System.out.println(b);` works on Oracle's JDK 8u65 for mac

Comment: @phflack My answer is written with the assumption that some of the inputs will actually be variables. In practice, you wouldn't write `byte b = (4 << 4) | 5`, you'd just write `byte b = 0x45;`, which is identical from from the compiler's point of view. But if the version or header length is a variable (not a compile-time constant), operations like `+` and `|` will require a cast to a `byte`.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

To make a compact field containing both Version and IHL in one byte, try doing

```
byte b = (byte)((Version << 4) + IHL);
```

This will only work if Version and IHL are numbers from 0 to 15

Comment: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte`

Comment: I'm using bytes for Version and IHL and not receiving the error

Comment: `<<`  is okay, actually, but `+` performs binary promotion to an `int` or `long`, depending on the widest operand. What are you compiling with? You might want to switch, as this code is invalid according to the [language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)

Comment: @erickson Probably like a two week old version of javac and java on Debian (pretty sure it's Debian)

Comment: 1.8.0_25-b17 says, `error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte`, 1.7.0_67-b01 says `error: possible loss of precision`. Eclipse gave the message I show above. You also have the the citation from the JLS.

Comment: @erickson Trying to reproduce how it managed to compile, and discovered that somehow `byte b = (5 << 4) + 4;` works, the numbers can be casted as an int or as a byte and still work, but any usage of actual variables breaks it, while casting the values does not

Comment: Yes, if you use compile-time constants, the compiler actually computes the value and stores it. The compiled byte code is exactly the same as if you wrote `byte b = 0x54;` However, `byte b = (0x08 << 4) | 0x04;` won't compile, because the result is too big for a `byte`. Also, if variables are used in the expression, as they are in your answer, it's a compile-time error, because the result of the right-hand side is an `int`, according to the JLS.

Comment: Did you want to correct your answer so that I can remove the downvote?

Comment: It's changed, and Java handles bytes really strangely in comparison to ints

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
    int a = 0x04;
    a <<= 4;
    a |= 0x05;
    System.out.println(a);
```

which essentially turns 0b00000100 into 0b01000000, then into 0b01000101.

Answer (score -1):

Just because a byte is 8 bits and your values can only be a maximum of 4 is not a problem. The extra 4 bits will just always be zeroes.

So if you were storing 1 for example:

0000 0001

or 15 (which is the maximum value right?):

0000 1111

Comment: Such doubts should be cleared in the comment section. This is not an answer

Comment: @FaizPinkman What doubts? I am giving a clear answer and I don't appreciate your downvote. I am saying just store it as a full byte anyway.

Comment: The question states how to fit in the two values into one byte

Answer (score -1):

Byte shifting is not possible in Java.

> [How does bitshifting work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312853/how-does-bitshifting-work-in-java)

However, as far as the logic is concerned, if you want the version and IHL in one byte, you could do it using the following

```
byte value = (byte) (IHL | VERSION << 4);
```

Comment: You seem to have Java confused with some other language, where a char would be equivalent to a byte.