# What is the return value of int plus uint?

Tags: c, arrays, int, uint

I have two variables:

```
int a;
uint b;
```

I also have an array:

```
float c[100];
```

If I want to pass `a+b` as the index of array `c` such that:

```
c[a+b] = 10.0;
```

For safety purpose, we should make sure `a+b` returns `uint`. Does it return `unit`?

Should I force its return value to be an `uint`?

Comment: What is `uint`? There is no such standard type in C. Is it a typedef for `unsigned int`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10047614/694576

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unsigned and signed values in C (what is the output)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668734/unsigned-and-signed-values-in-c-what-is-the-output)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, when you add an `int` and an `unsigned int`, the `int` value gets promoted to `unsigned int`, so you'll be fine. Be careful that a isn't negative, however, or you'll be in for a nasty surprise!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What it a is negative? How can it be promoted to unsigned int?

Comment: @UKYECE Technically that should be a new question - "What happens if I cast a negative value to `unsigned int`?"

Comment: @immibis technically it should be "What happens when a negative `int` is converted to `unsigned int`?". A cast requires a cast operator.

Comment: It's not particularly nasty: the negative int gets `UINT_MAX+1` added to it, to make it a positive `unsigned int` .  `-1 + 5u` gives `4u` .

Comment: is that "assuming 2s complement", or is it a standards guarantee?

Comment: @sp2danny it's a standards guarantee.

Comment: @sp2danny: If N is positive, adding -N to, or subtracting N from, an unsigned integer value will yield the number which, when added to N, would yield the original.  The fact that (unsigned)-1 is UINT_MAX has nothing to do with twos-complement notation and everything to do with the fact that (UINT_MAX+1)==0u.