# Why has the Int32 type a maximum value of 2³¹ − 1?

Tags: c#, types, integer

I know [`Int32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32) has a length of 32 bits (4 bytes). I assume it has 2³² values but as half of them must be under zero, I guess it has something to do with this.

I would like to know why exactly `Int32` has maximum positive number 2³¹ − 1.

Comment: duplicate of [Why is the maximum value of an unsigned n-bit integer 2^n-1 and not 2^n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771520/why-is-the-maximum-value-of-an-unsigned-n-bit-integer-2n-1-and-not-2n)

Comment: Related: [What is “2's Complement”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/2s-complement-defined)

Answer (score 65):

This most significant bit is used to code the sign (1 meaning negative), so only 31 bits are available for the actual value.

```
Int32.MaxValue =  2^31 - 1 = 01111111111111111111111111111111
                  1        = 00000000000000000000000000000001
                  0        = 00000000000000000000000000000000
                 -1        = 11111111111111111111111111111111
Int32.MinValue = -2^31     = 10000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: If we are going to consider 0 as positive number(hypothetically), then we have equal number of values besides the imaginary line between -1 and 0 .

Answer (score 39):

2³² possible values

− 2³¹ values used for [negative integers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

− 1 value used for zero

= 2³¹ − 1 values available for positive integers

Answer (score 32):

2³² is about 4.2 billion.  This is the maximum number of VALUES that a binary number with 32 digits (a 32-bit number) can represent.

Those values can be any values in any range.  In an UNSIGNED 32-bit number, the valid values are from 0 to 2³² − 1 (instead of 1 to 2³², but the same number of VALUES, about 4.2 billion).

In a SIGNED 32-bit number, one of the 32 bits is used to indicate whether the number is negative or not.  This reduces the number of values by a factor of 2¹, or by half.  This leaves 2³¹, which is about 2.1 billion.  This means the range is now about −2.1 billion to 2.1 billion.  Same number of values, different range.

Comment: @HashimAziz: The flaw being that, without referencing two's complement representation, it doesn't explain why the maximum value is 2³¹ − 1, while the minimum is -2³¹.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2^31 values below zero (minimum value = -2^31), 2^31-1 values above zero and zero itself. That makes 2^31 + 2^31-1 + 1 = 2*2^31 = 2^32 values :) ...

The other explanation involves the way how negative numbers are represented (using the two-complement): Shortly, the most-significant bit indicates a negative number, so you have 2^31 positive numbers (including zero) left, which gives us the range 0..2^31-1