# Can't assign 32bit hexadecimal value to integer

Tags: c#, types, hex, unsigned, signed

> First, this question has related posts:
>   [Why Int32 maximum value is 0x7FFFFFFF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13230041/975724)

However, I want to know why the hexadecimal value is always treated as an unsigned quantity.

See the following snippet:

```
byte  a = 0xFF;               //No error (byte is an unsigned type).
short b = 0xFFFF;             //Error! (even though both types are 16 bits).
int   c = 0xFFFFFFFF;         //Error! (even though both types are 32 bits).
long  d = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF; //Error! (even though both types are 64 bits).
```

The reason for the error is because the hexadecimal values are always treated as unsigned values, regardless of what data-type they are stored as.  Hence, the value is *'too large'* for the data-type described.

---

For instance, I expected:

```
int c = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

To store the value:

```
-1
```

And not the value:

```
4294967295
```

Simply because `int` is a *signed* type.

---

So, why is it that the hexadecimal values are always treated as unsigned even if the sign type can be inferred by the data-type used to store them?

How can I store these bits into these data-types without resorting to the use of `ushort`, `uint`, and `ulong`?

In particular, how can I achieve this for the `long` data-type considering I cannot use a larger signed data-type?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Int32 maximum value is 0x7FFFFFFF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230041/why-int32-maximum-value-is-0x7fffffff)

Comment: @RowlandShaw Sorry, but it doesn't answer my question.  I've even linked to that...

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here... you could put that value into a decimal type but something tells me that's not really what you want.

Comment: Just type `var value = 0x7ffffff;` in your text editor.  Hover the mouse over "var" and you'll see that it is *not* unsigned.  The compiler simply picks the smallest integral value type that fits the value, starting at `int`.  If you want to intentionally overflow an assignment then you have to use the `unchecked` keyword to stop the compiler from telling you that you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's going on is that a literal is intrinsically typed.  `0.1` is a `double`, which is why you can't say `float f = 0.1`.  You can *cast* a `double` to a `float` (`float f = (float)0.1`), but you may lose precision.  Similarly, the literal 0xFFFFFFFF is intrinsically a `uint`.  You can cast it to an `int`, but that's *after* it has been interpreted by the compiler as a `uint`.  The compiler doesn't use the variable to which you are assigning it to figure out its type; its type is defined by what sort of literal it is.

Comment: Actually, 1.5 is a bad example, as it can be represented as a sum of fractions with denominators that are powers of 2, so will be exact

Comment: Yeah, good point.  I should say "you may lose precision."  (And in the case of 1.5, you won't)

Comment: I replaced 1.5 with 0.1 to simplify things.

Answer (score 0):

They are treated as unsigned numbers, as that is [what the language specification says to do](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029)