# What is the significance of the number, 32767?

Tags: types, integer

I realize in some programming languages, random number generators generate a default value of 0 to 32767 (for example, in php, rand(); will return a float between 0 and 32767).  What is the significance of such a random number? (As it is not a power of two or anything special like that.)

Comment: Maybe read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558271/why-the-range-of-int-is-32768-to-32767

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is 2^15-1, so the maximum value of a 16-bit signed integer.

Comment: Yeah, this is a good answer and 7 years later as a CS Major in college, I understand what it means! I was pretty clueless back in high school :)) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I guess, On 16-bit implementations (still common when the C89 standard was written) that was the largest signed integer.

Answer (score -1):

32767 + 1 is a power of 2
Binary representation of numbers uses powers of 2.  So, in an 4-bit structure, `0101` is 2^0 x 1, 2^1 x 0, 2^2 x 1, and 2^3 x 0 which is 5.

The MSB is used for sign and unsigned integers.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. FPK's answer is correct