# Why 32767+1 gives -32768 in Turbo C?

Tags: c, int, turbo-c

When I add 32767 to 1 in an integer variable in Turbo C, i get -32768 whereas I should get 32768.

I want to know why this happens.

Comment: 16 bit int overflow.

Comment: Your answer is here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558271/why-the-range-of-int-is-32768-to-32767

Comment: signed integer overflow is UB, anyway.

Comment: This is **undefined behaviour** because of a signed integer overflow (your `int` is 16-bit wide 2's complement). Note that you even **could** get 32768 on some other platform when overflowing 16-bit signed integer.

Comment: @Nick no, that is not the proper place. It just says what is the range of `int` in Turbo C.

Comment: reopened: the old "duplicate" was explaining why ranges are sized as they are; this question is different

Answer (score 4, accepted):

32767 and 1 both fit in an `int`, so they're constants of type `int`. In Turbo C `int` has range of -32768 to 32767 (they're 16-bit 2's complement signed integers). When you add an `int` to an `int`, there are no promotions on either side, and the result will be also of type `int`. However 32767 + 1 is not representable in a signed `int` - it is outside the limits of the type. This is called signed integer overflow.

According to C standard when signed integer overflow occurs, the **behaviour of the program is undefined**. In this case it wraps the value around; e.g. when you add `1` to `0b0111111111111111`, you get `0b1000000000000000`, which is interpreted as `-32768`.

However the C standard does not mandate any wraparound on signed integer overflow - anything may happen. Your program can even behave like the result is positive 32768 (even though not representable by a 16-bit `int` - this is actually quite probable on 32-bit and 64-bit processors - the compiler knows that *since the number never is going to overflow*, the compiler can use a wider register for it). Or your program may crash with an exception, or it may cause demons fly out of your nose.

Answer (score 1):

Integer overflow invokes **undefined behaviour**. So the result can be -32768, 32768, 0, or any number. It's even possible for your program to crash or print one of Willian Shakespeare's poem.

Comment: Turbo C is C as much as any other C is C