# Unexpected output of C++ programm

Tags: c++

I compiled the following code in **turbo C** compiler

```
void main()
{
  int i =400*400/400;

  if(i==400)
    cout<<"Filibusters";
  else
    cout<<"Sea ghirkins";
}
```

I expected the value of **'i'** to be **400** and hence, the output should be **Filibusters**. However, the output I got is **Sea Ghirkins**. How is this possible?

Comment: It should be `int main` for a start

Comment: print out `i` and see if it meets your expectations.

Comment: What does `sizeof(int)` return?

Comment: Dont compile with a compiler that's been obsolete for over 10 years.

Comment: 400*400 is 160000, which is larger than 16 bits. I suspect Turbo C uses 16 bit `int`s.

Comment: @GillBates AFAIK Turbo C++ has been obsolete since 1998.

Comment: @NathanOliver It was revived in 2006 :D

Comment: @GillBates When then Frankensteined it they must have used [Abby Normal's brain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yH97lImrr0Q).

Comment: @GillBates: I am almost certain the OP is using a 1980s version through a DOS emulator. That's beyond obsolete.

Comment: The smell is indeed of Turbo C++ 3.0. The Turbo C++ of 2006 was a hacked-down C++ builder and reasonably up to date for it's time.

Comment: @ShubhamBhatia is anything left unclear to you?

Comment: @fukanchik no its crystal clear now!

Answer (score 5):

You are *overflowing* your `int` type: the behaviour on doing that is *undefined*.

The range of an `int` can be as small as -32767 to +32767. Check the value of `sizeof int`. If it's 2, then it will not be able to represent 400 * 400. You can also check the values of INT_MAX and INT_MIN.

Use a `long` instead, which must be at least 32 bits. And perhaps treat yourself to a new compiler this weekend?

Comment: The question was originally asked in turbo, and who doesn't know about c++14. I just wanted to know the output in turbo.

Comment: How in the great googly mooglies did C++14 get involved? This has been law since time immemorial. 400 * 400 likely equals 28928 (0x7100) due to 16 bit overflow. 28928 / 400  = 72.

Comment: @user4581301 If the size of integer is 4 bytes, then it would run as expected, the mention of c++14 is just to signify that the question was particularly asked to be compiled in turbo!

Comment: @ShubhamBhatia That is true if the size of `int` is 4 bytes. Bathsheba's point is a 4 byte `int` is not required by the standard, and this goes back past the origins of C++ and into it's roots in C. If you have Turbo C++ 3, designed for good ol' DOS and 16 bit Windows 3, the `int` only supports the bare minimum 16 bits. More recent TurboC++ used larger `int`s to keep pace with the native sizes of newer CPUs. If your code fails to produce 400, you likely have TurboC++ 3 or older.

Answer (score 3):

Look at operator [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence): `*` and `/` are left-associative, that means your formula is calculated in this order: `(400*400)/400`

`400*400=160000`. Computer arithmetic is finite. You are using 16-bit compiler where `int` fits into 16 bits and can only hold values from range `-32768 ... 32767` ([why -32768](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558271/why-the-range-of-int-is-32768-to-32767)?). 160000 obviously doesn't fit into that range and is trimmed ([*integer overflow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) occurs). Then you divide trimmed value by 400 and get something unexpected to you.  Compilers of the past were quite straightforward so I would expect something like 72 to be stored into `i`.

The above means you can either use a bigger integer type - `long` which is able to store `160000` or change assiciativity manually using parenthesses: `400*(400/400)`.

Comment: "You are using 16-bit compiler" not necessarily: a 128 bit compiler can still have a 16 bit int. Also your lower limit of -32768 is only true for 2's complement int. Other than that, this answer is cute.