# VBA array size reset once hitting 32767 (Excel 2010)

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I use a 1D dynamic array to hold values that total numbers of them will be 60K plus. This seems like an easy task but I noticed that once the size of the array reaches 32767, it started from 0 again. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

My code:

```
Sub GetHours()

Dim R As Long, i As Long, N As Long, var, vRaw, v

R = LastUsedRow(Sheet1)
With Sheet1
      vRaw = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(R, 22)).Value
End With

For i = 1 To R - 1
    var = vRaw(i, 12)
    If IsNumeric(var) Then
        If IsArrayEmpty(v) Then
            ReDim v(0)
            v(0) = i
        Else
            N = UBound(v) + 1
            ReDim Preserve v(N)
            v(N) = i
        End If

    End If
Next

End Sub

Function LastUsedRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet) As Long

Dim lastrow As Long

On Error GoTo errHandler
lastrow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                         SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

LastUsedRow = lastrow
Exit Function

errHandler:
    LastUsedRow = 0

End Function

Function IsArrayEmpty(anArray As Variant)
Dim i As Integer
On Error Resume Next
i = UBound(anArray, 1)

If Err.Number = 0 Then
    IsArrayEmpty = False
Else
    IsArrayEmpty = True
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Let me guess: you are using Excel in a version previous to 2013, and that's the maximum allowed as a range for this Excel spreadsheet, and that's why it reset. If that's not the case, please add the Excel version you're using to your question.

Comment: This may be of some interest to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18558328/3380970

Comment: Thanks Hila. No, I am actually using Excel 2010 which allows 1048576 rows.

Comment: Where's the code for LastUsedRow?

Comment: To xiience, I declared N as the long data type, I thought it should be adequate in dealing with size growth of the array

Comment: IsArrayEmpty may also be important...

Comment: To Tim, just added the function in my post. Though I don't think the function caused the problem. The code worked fine if the N is less than 32767.

Comment: Maybe you are using Excel 2010 but the file is saved as Excel xls (93-2003 version) and not as xlsx?

Comment: To Hida, the file is saved as a binary file.

Comment: Hida - previous row limit was 64k not 32k

Comment: put a break on `ReDim v(0)` and see when it runs.  Note you have `Dim i As Integer` in that last function...  That will trigger an out of bounds error above ~32k which will then trigger your array to be reset

Comment: To Tim, you are the champ!!! Thank you so much. I would never think about it.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note you have Dim i As Integer in that last IsArrayEmpty function...

That will trigger an out of bounds error above ~32k which will then trigger your array to be reset.

Comment: Yes indeed. Again, much appreciated.