# Decimal to Binary with two complement

Tags: c++, binary

I tried to convert decimal to binary like this:
I got input int and a binary int.

```
int rem;
int bin[32] = {0};

for(int i=0; input != 0; i++) { //making array of binary, but reversed
    rem = input%2;
    bin[i] = abs(rem);
    input = input / 2;
}

for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++) { //reversed binary is put in correct order
    binary[i] = bin[31 - i];
}
```

now I want that if the input is negative like "-5" it gives me the two-complement.

When trying to complement every bit with "~", they turn to "-1" somehow.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    binary[i] = ~binary[i];
}
```

Comment: That's because they aren't bits, they're `int`s. If an `int` stores a `0` and you invert all its bits in two's complement, you indeed get `-1`.

Comment: `binary[i] = 1 - binary[i];` might be what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.

You store one bit per `int`, so you need to flip only that bit with for example `^ 1` (XOR 1). That way 0 becomes 1 and 1 becomes 0. The tilde operator `~` will flip all the bits, so 0 becomes -1, and 1 becomes -2 (i.e. not what you want).

Then, to negate a two's complement number, you need to

1. invert it
2. add `1` ([why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833773/why-we-need-to-add-1-while-doing-2s-complement))

For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    binary[i] ^= 1;
}

for (int i = 31; i >= 0; i--) {
    binary[i] ^= 1;
    if (binary[i])
        break;
}
```

Or combine the two steps into one:

```
for (int i = 31, carry = 0; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (carry || !binary[i]) {
        binary[i] ^= 1;
        carry = 1;
    }
}
```