# Explain the result of the program?

Tags: c, output

The output of below c program is,
output : 1,2,3,4 ........ 126,127,-128,-127 .... -2,-1 ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char i=0;
   for(i<=5 && i>=-1 ; ++i;i>0)
     printf("%d\n",i);
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
```

}

please explain why is so ?

Comment: `char` is a signed 8-bit value.

Comment: I think you slightly mixed the components of your for loop.

Comment: @Joe It is signed in the OPs compiler, but it doesn't have to be. It's implementation specified.

Comment: please add the `void` parameter to your definition of `main()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a breakdown of your code, it's fairly sneaky:

```
for( i <= 5 && i >= -1 ; ++i; i > 0)
```

Typically a for-loop is, ( initial statement, expression, second statement ). Looking at your code before the first null statement: what you have done is an expression (in place of a statement), which does not matter at all however it's entirely useless. So removing that line (which has no effect on the result of this expression) gives us:

```
for( ; ++i; i > 0)
```

... now if you noticed you initialized `i` to be 0 before the for loop. What you are doing next is incrementing `i` and then returning its value (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators)), and hence it will go from 1 ... -1 (overflowing at 127). This is because in C any non-zero value is `true` and 0 is `false`. Hence, once `i` becomes 0 it will stop running the loop. `i` can only become zero by overflowing.

Your third statement does not matter, it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

It is called overflow. Type "char" uses 1 byte of your RAM's capacity, so it can store only 256 values. These are [-128, 127]. When you try to get over 127, it will get back the the lowest value.

Other than that, your for loop is a little messed up. Try

```
for ( i = 0 ; i <= 5 ; ++i ) // This will print 0,1,2,3,4,5
    printf( "%d\n" , i );
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this:

```
for(i<=5 && i>=-1 ; ++i;i>0)
```

works out as

1) Initialisation:

```
   i<=5 && i>=-1
```

does nothing

2) Termination condition:

```
   ++i
```

increments i and will terminate when i gets to zero

3) statement executed each time round loop (normally an increment / decrement):

```
   i > 0
```

does nothing.

So your code loops from i = 0 back till it's zero again

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're using the for loop incorrectly.

`for(i<=5 && i>=-1 ; ++i;i>0)`

The above code means:

1. Before anything, evaluate `i<=5 && i>=-1` (which doesn't have any side effects so nothing happens)
2. On every iteration, increment `i` then check if it is zero. If it is non-zero, run another iteration.
3. At the end of every iteration, evaluate `i>0` (which again, does nothing).

Therefore, your loop simplifies down to and is essentially

`while (++i)`

To explain your result, the system you're using is likely using implements a char as a signed [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) integer which 'wraps' to a negative number when it is higher than 127 (since 128 in a 8 bit two's complement integer is a -128)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, char occupies 1 byte and it is signed.
With the help of 8 bits (1 byte) the range of numbers that you can represent is

```
**-(2^(8-1)) to +((2^(8-1)) -1) [ie from -128 to +127].**
```

In your code you are incrementing i and also printing the same.
once i reaches 127 (in binary 0111 1111 = 127) and you again increment it becomes (1000 0000) which is -128.

And while printing you are using %d. so out will be in integer format.
That is why it is printing 1,2,3 ... -128, -127...

If you didn't understand how 1000 0000 is -128, read

[What is 2's Complement Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728492/what-is-2s-complement-number/16728502#16728502)