# Not understanding output related to bitfields

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    struct value
    {
    int bit1:1;
    int bit3:4;
    int bit4:4;
    }bit={1,8,15};
    printf("%d%d%d",bit.bit1,bit.bit3,bit.bit4);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is: -1-8-1

I know it is because of unsigned bit, but explain it more to me. Can't get why 8 prints -8 and why 15 prints -1.

Comment: Check what is 2's complement here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728492/what-is-2s-complement-number/16728502#16728502

Answer (score 4):

```
int bit4:4;
```

is signed so has range [-8..7].  Setting it to 15 is equivalent to 0b1111.  Which is equivalent to -1 assuming [2s complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Similarly for `bit3`, 8 is equivalent to 0b1000.  The top bit tells you this is a negative value.  Inverting the other bits then adding 1 gives you -8.

If you want to store values [8..15], you either need a 5-bit signed value or to change the type to `unsigned int`

Comment: It is implementation-defined whether `int bit4:4;` defines a signed or unsigned bit-field (it is clearly signed **in the OP's particular case**). If you **want** a signed bit-field, write `signed int bit4:4;` C99 6.7.2:5

Answer (score 1):

With four bits, the sixteen bit combinations are [interpreted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) as follows:

```
0000 : 0
0001 : 1
0010 : 2
0011 : 3
0100 : 4
0101 : 5
0110 : 6
0111 : 7
1000 : -8
1001 : -7
1010 : -6
1011 : -5
1100 : -4
1101 : -3
1110 : -2
1111 : -1
```

The numbers that you set correspond to `0001` (1), `1000` (-8) and `1111` (-1).

Comment: OP, just FYI, the blinking lights just explained 2s complement without saying it.  I'm pointing it out because it confused the hell out of me when I started...

Comment: @JimR That's why I included a link at the top :)