# Bit sign of uint32_t -1 instead of 1 in C

Tags: c, bit, sign, uint32-t

I have done

```
uint32_t bits= 0;

bits |= 1<< 31;
```

and then using

```
void printbits(uint32_t n) {
    if (n) {
        printbits(n >> 1);
        printf("%d", n & 1);
    }
}
```

on bits I get 10000000000000000000000000000000, which is what I want, but when I use my getbit(bits, 0)

```
int get_bit(int n, int bitnr) {
    int mask = 1 << bitnr;
    int masked_n = n & mask;
    int thebit = masked_n >> bitnr;
    return thebit;
}
```

I get a -1 instead of 1, any idea why?

Thank's!

Comment: It's probably doing an [arithmetic shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift), that's a common choice for how to implement right shifts on signed types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right Shifting a signed number and if the number is negative is implementation behavior.

According to the Section 6.5.7 of the latest draft standard, this behavior on negative numbers is implementation dependent:

```
The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1 has an 
unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of 
the result is the integral part of the quotient of E1 / 2E2. If E1 has a signed
type and a negative value, the resulting value is implementation-defined.
```

**Edit:**
Please do refer, how a number is represented here https://stackoverflow.com/a/16728502/1814023

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printbits(int n);
int get_bit(int n, int bitnum);

int
main()
{
    int bits = 0;

    bits |= 1 << 31;
    printbits(bits);

    bits = 0xf0f0f0f0;
    printbits(bits);  

    return(0);
}

void
printbits(int n)
{
    int j;

    for (j = 0; j < 32; j++) {
            printf("%d", get_bit(n, j));
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int
get_bit(int n, int bitnum)
{
    return((n >> (31 - bitnum)) & 1);
}
```

When compiled and run, it should output

```
10000000000000000000000000000000
11110000111100001111000011110000
```

Comment: but my problem is in get_bit

Comment: I have extracted the line from printbits and created a separate get_bit function.