# NOT or compliment of a number?

Tags: binary, logic, boolean-logic

assume: 2's compliment, integer.
just a quick question. why is it that If a had a number, and take the NOT of it, that it will equal negative +or- 1. for example:

```
553481923
~553481923 = -553481924
2147455726
~2147455726 = -2147455727
-2147455725
~-2147455725 =2147455724
```

I understand that the bits are inverted. is there any reason for this happening, or is this just coincidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the way 2's complement notation works.

The range of 2's complement integer is `(-2^31) to (2^31 - 1)`

Take for example the 2's complement 8 bit value:

```
0000 0000 = 0 (base 10)
```

and the 2's complement negative 8 bit value:

```
1111 1111 = -1 (base 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you can express one additional negative value in a 2's complement system, because `00000000` is zero. That means that out of all of the positive numbers which you can express (up to `01111111`), you will still be shorted that one extra bit. On the other hand, you get `10000000` as a negative number. (I have been using bytes, but this applies to words of any length.)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1049774/691859