# Why does this pointer manipulation code yield 33554432?

Tags: c

```
int *q,a[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
char *p;
p=(char*)a;  
p++;
q=(int*)p;
printf("\n%d",*q);
```

Please explain for me why display is 33554432

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518018/how-is-an-integer-stored-in-memory

Answer (score 4):

Assuming we have 4-byte integers, stored in little-endian fashion (lowest byte first), the array is stored (in bytes) as:

```
01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 ...etc.
```

`p` points to the second byte, and `q` points to the integer starting at that same place, so:

```
   00 00 00 02
```

since we're stored low-to-high, that integer is:

```
0x02000000
```

in hex, or `33554432` in decimal.

Comment: or 2*2^24 = 2^25 = 33554432 in decimal....

Comment: It is also undefined behavior.