# Right shift operator does not work in flags enum

Tags: c#

I have following enum with flags attribute:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
{
    None = 0,
    First = 1,
    Second= 2,
    Third= 4,
       .
       .
       .
    Unknown = All >> 1,
    All = ~None,
}
```

and I want the `Unknown` value to be the last before the `All` value. So I thought that the right-shift operator will do the work, but when I print both of the values to console like this:

```
Console.WriteLine((int)MyEnum.All);
Console.WriteLine((int)MyEnum.Unknown);
```

it prints `-1` and `-1`.
What am I doing wrong and how can I modify the code to have `Unknown` right before `All`?

**Edit:** thanks to everyone for the asnwers, I overlooked that the right-shift operator performs arithmetic shift and "propagates the sign bit to the high-order empty bit positions". In the end I realized that my approach would give me wrong results anyway because `MyEnum.Unknown.HasFlag(MyEnum.First);` would return true and that would be incorrect behavior. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66126835/5632590) pointed me to the right direction and I set `Unknown` to `int.MinValue` and that is excatly what I wanted to accomplish - I wanted `Unknown` to be like any other value and also be the highest possible one. Now Im just embarrassed that I did not think about that earlier...

Comment: From [Right-shift operator >>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators#right-shift-operator-): "If the left-hand operand is of type `int` or `long`, the right-shift operator performs an _arithmetic_ shift: the value of the most significant bit (the sign bit) of the left-hand operand is propagated to the high-order empty bit positions."

Comment: For completeness, from [Enumeration types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum): "By default, the associated constant values of enum members are of type `int`; they start with zero and increase by one following the definition text order."

Comment: `Unknown = (int)unchecked(((uint)All) >> 1),`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you want `All` to be `0xFFFFFFFF` and `Unknown` to be `0x8000000` so that `Unknown` is included in `All`. Interesting idea. Perhaps `0x7FFFFFFF` and `0x8000000` would make more sense:

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    [Flags]
    public enum MyEnum : uint
    {
    None = 0,
    First = 1,
    Second= 2,
    Third= 4, // ...
    Unknown = (uint)1 << 31, // Most-significant-bit.
    All = ~Unknown}

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("All: " + ((uint)MyEnum.All).ToString("X"));
        Console.WriteLine("Unknown: " + ((uint)MyEnum.Unknown).ToString("X"));
    }
}
```

[.NETfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3zcTCo).

Answer (score 0):

Enumerations are based on signed integers, namely `int`.

If you play with any integers, you'll that this behaviour is totally correct (output from C# interactive):

```
> int i = 0;
> int j = ~i;
> j
-1
> int k = j >> 1;
> k
-1
```

For more depth explanation and understanding I recommend reading through [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18518018/how-is-an-integer-stored-in-memory). It has even answer from one of a guys working on C# language :)

But hte baseline is: what you are seeing is totally correct and works that way because enums are `int`s underneath, unless you specify otherwise (you can use `uint` instead of `long`):

```
public enum LongEnum : long
{
    //values
}
```

Comment: To clarify you can override the default "int" behavior by doing this `public enum MyEnum : uint {...}`

Comment: @Andy yes, i was just writing that :)

Comment: Hmm.. If I do this: `public enum MyEnum : uint {...}` I still get sign extension behavior (both `All` and `Unknown` end up equal to `4294967295`).  Do you want the high bit to be zero?  You may want to clear that bit with `All & 7FFF_FFFF`.

Answer (score 0):

may be it fits for you:

```
  0     0x00000000     None
  1     0x00000001     First
  2     0x00000002     Second
  4     0x00000004     Third
 -2     0xFFFFFFFE     Unknown
 -1     0xFFFFFFFF     All
```

code:

```
using System;

[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
{
    None = 0,
    First = 1,
    Second= 2,
    Third= 4,
    Unknown = All << 1,
    All = ~None,
}

public class Example {
    public static void Main() {
        foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0,3}     0x{0:X8}     {1}",
                           (int) value, ((MyEnum) value));
        }   
    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following may help. 'All' covers all the bits apart from the most significant bit. The most significant bit is used for 'Unknown'.

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum : uint
{
    None = 0,
    First = 1,
    Second = 2,
    Third = 4,
    All = uint.MaxValue >> 1,
    Unknown = ~All,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, *right shift* `>>` works different for `int` and `uint` when the most significant bit is set to `1`:

```
int  : 1.... >> 1 == 11.... : sign bit (which is 1 here) propagates
uint : 1.... >> 1 == 01.... : 0 added
```

You want the *second type* behaviour, which is demonstrated by `uint`, so let's cast `All` to `uint` while doing right shift:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
{
    None = 0,
    ...
    Unknown = (int)unchecked(((uint)All) >> 1),
    All = ~None,
}
```

I would not recommend `public enum MyEnum : uint` declaration since `uint` is not *cls compliant*.