# Negation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, negation

Can someone explain why Javascript gives the following results?

```
~3 = -4
~3.346346 = -4
~-3 = 2
```

Comment: See and understand two's complement: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement

Comment: The output of the first one is also `2`. You seem to have messed up your examples.

Comment: @Stijn No, the example given is correct.

Comment: @Jeremy I was basing it off the fixed edit, as it wasn't until after the fix that Stijn's comment appeared (for me).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`~` is the **[bitwise negation operator<sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)**.

`3` in binary (using a 32-bit integer) is

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 (3)
```

and `-3` in  binary (using [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)) is

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1101 (-3)
```

The `~` operator reverses all of the `1`s to `0`s and all the `0`s to `1`, so `~3` will be

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100 (~3 == -4)
```

which is binary for `-4` (using [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)).

Similarly, `~-3` will be

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 (~-3 == 2)
```

which is binary for `2`.

`3.346346` will be cast to an integer when doing bitwise operations, so it will have the same result as `3` had.

---

To sum up:

```
  3 = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0011 = (int)3.346346
 ~3 = 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100 = -4
 -3 = 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1101
~-3 = 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 =  2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because negative numbers are stored as *two's complement*:

```
minusB = ~B + 1;
```

In your case, reversing the formula above:

- `-3` is stored as `~3 + 1`. So, `~-3` is equivalent to `-(-3) - 1 = 2`.
- `~3.346346` is first rounded to `3`, then `~3` can be read as `-3 - 1 = -4`

The reason why *two's complement* is used (instead of using a separate bit for sign), is that it makes subtraction and addition trivial, regardless of signs.