# Working out decimal in Sign and Magnitude

Tags: decimal, sign

I know how to work out `-10` in Sign and Magnitude in a 9 bits memory location:

I first calculated the decimal in positive (`+10`) and then add a sign`(1)` in front that indicates negative, which gives me the answer: `100001010`

But when it comes to the decimal `-256`

I first calculated the positive number`(256)`, which gives `100000000`, but how can I turn this to negative? because there are no more spaces for me to add a sign in front, and the sum of the first 8 bits is only `255`, which cannot give me the answer of `256`.

I was just wondering is this even possible?

Comment: If you have eight bits to represent the number, then the largest number you can have is 11111111(2), i.e. 255(10) - where the number in parentheses represents the number base. If you have eight bits and a sign bit, then 100000000(2) represents -0.

Comment: Does that mean -256 is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to represent -256 with one sign bit and eight magnitude bits.

If you have eight bits to represent the number, then the largest number you can have is 11111111(2), i.e. 255(10) - where the number in parentheses represents the number base. If you have eight bits and a sign bit, then 100000000(2) represents -0 and 111111111(2) represents -255(10).

Given nine bits, you *could* use [two's complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement) to represent numbers from -256 to 255.