# Multiple casts in succession not working as intended

Tags: java

As per my understanding, casts are used to convert a value from one type to another.

I found the following program in the book "Java Puzzlers: Traps, Pitfalls, and Corner Cases" by Joshua Bloch and Neal Gafter

This program uses three casts in succession:

> ```
> public class Multicast {  
>     public static void main(String[] args) {  
>       System.out.println((int) (char) (byte) -1);  
>   }  
> }
> ```

I thought it will print -1 but it is printing It prints 65535, but why?

Comment: already answered in great detail  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635977/why-does-intcharbyte-2-produce-65534-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Expression: `(int) (char) (byte) -1`

1. `-1` is of type int
2. `(byte) -1` is a byte with value -1
3. `(char) (byte) -1` first the byte with value -1 is sign extended again to be an 32-bit integer of value -1. This means that all the 32-bit are set to 1 (the two-complement encoding of -1 in 32 bits). Then it is cast to the type `char` which is an unsigned 16-bit value, so you get 16 bits set to one, which has the value 65535.
4. `(int) (char) (byte) -1` by explicitly casting it again to a 32-bit integer, you make sure that it is printed as a number instead of the character with the codepoint 65535.

Answer (score 1):

A char in java is an unsigned 16-bit integer. If you cast a negative integer literal like -1 to a char, then the value is interpreted as a positive number; in this case 65535- or Unicode character \uFFBF.

Check this -1 cast with char only,

```
System.out.println( (char) -1);
```

If it cast with `int` or `byte` type, this returns `-1` only.