# I am assuming size of integer 2 byte and getting different value in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main() 
{
unsigned int i=65535;//assume that size of integer is 2 byte
printf("%d",i);
}
```

output=-1 //if size of integer is 2 byte

output=65535// if size of integer is 4 byte

can anyone explain me why it print -1 instead of 65535

according to me 
 Size of interger is 2 byte i.e 16 bit . i=65535(Decimal value) Binary representation of 65535 is 1111111111111111. so it can accommodate 65535 easily

Comment: A **signed** 16bit integer normally has a range of -32768 to 32767 and binary 1111.... equals -1. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement) provides many details abpout 2's complement

Comment: What C implementation are you using, on what system? Is it an embedded system? (That's the only valid excuse for using `void main()`.) On modern systems, it's much more common for `int` to be 4 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `"%u"` conversion, rather than `"%d"`. These are the conversion specifiers for `unsigned` (int) and `signed` (int) respectively.

Comment: ya i agree with u brett .but i am curious to know this result with %d conversion

Comment: Size of interger is 2 byte i.e 16 bit . i=65535(Decimal value) Binary representation of 65535 is 1111111111111111
so it can easily accommodate 65535 and should be print 65535

Comment: @anshumansingh - "%d" specifies that the argument is to be interpreted as a *signed* integer value. e.g., `-1` is `0xffff` in 2's complement representation. Values: `2^15 .. 2^16 - 1` yield: `-32768 .. -1`