# A bit field of enumeration type and a value stored to it

Tags: c++, enumeration, bit-fields

I wrote the following and I expected that `16` would be printed.

```
#include <iostream>

enum E : long { e = 16 };

struct X 
{
    E e : 5;
};

X x;


int main(){ x.e = E::e; std::cout << static_cast<int>(x.e) << std::endl; }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7add5b99afbf91d3)**

But it wasn't. I got a compiler warning and `-16` was printed instead. The warning was:

```
warning: implicit truncation from 'E' to bitfield changes value from 16 to -16
```

It's unclear to me. Why was the warning display and why was `-16` printed? I declared the bit-field of size of `5` that's enough to store `16` in there.

Comment: 5 bits is not enough to hold 16 if the type is signed. Change the enum's underlying type to `unsigned` and your code should work.

Comment: I think you want `unsigned long` ... http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a1576333fd7ec55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [two's complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement) issue with signed values.  You're going out of range of what a 5-bit signed value can represent.

If you only have 5 bits to store the value of 16, you'll have `10000`.  The leading `1` indicates that this is a negative value.  Only 4 bits represent the magnitude when you have 5 bits for a signed value.  To determine the absolute value of a 2s complement value, you flip all the bits and add 1, so

`10000` -> `01111` -> `10000` which is 16, so it's negative 16.

Your options would be to use 6 bits instead of 5 if you want to represent the signed range of values, or use an `unsigned long` in which case you can use all 5 bits for the magnitude

Comment: Thanks for your response, but as far as I know it's implementation defined if either two's complement or signed magnitude is used. Right?

Comment: More precisely _this International Standard
permits 2’s complement, 1’s complement and signed magnitude representations for integral types._ from 3.9.1/8

Comment: if you use `long` then it's a signed value.  C++ doesn't require that signed values be implemented as two's complement, but you are out of the range of values that can be represented by this value.  If you use `unsigned long` it will be an unsigned value.

Comment: You're getting `-16` because you're using two's complement.   signed integer overflow is undefined by the standard so you could get `0` for all you know, the compiler knows what's going on though and is telling you what it's actually doing to cope

Comment: _because you're using two's complement_ Why that? _C++ doesn't require that signed values be implemented as two's complement_ I haven't come across the requirements, couldn't you get the reference?

Comment: You're using two's complement because that's what your hardware is using.  It's true that C++ doesn't require two's complement but none of the representations you mention will be able to hold 16.

Comment: what I'm saying is that once you exceed the maximum value `X::e` can hold for positives, C++ doesn't care what happens.  However there is an implementation-specific reason you are specifically getting 16, which is what I was explaining.  Unless I'm misunderstanding your confusion