# Why does '0xcafebabe' stand for a different number in Scala and Python?

Tags: python, scala

Here's the code and result:

```
python2.7 >>> 0xcafebabe
3405691582

scala2.10.4> 0xcafebabe
res0: Int = -889275714
```

Why is the hex number '0xcafebabe' a negative number in Scala?

**P.S.**: I find it related to the overflow of Int. But when I specify a variable as Long, why does it still not as expected?

```
scala> val aa = 0xcafebabeL
aa: Long = 3405691582

scala> val aa1:Long = 0xcafebabe
aa1: Long = -889275714
```

**P.S. 2**: When I try to evaluate a variable as Int with 3405691582, the Scala prompt complains `error: integer number too large`, whereas if 0xcafebabe is applied, no error is thrown. Why is that?

```
scala> val aa:Int = 3405691582
<console>:1: error: integer number too large
       val aa:Int = 3405691582
                    ^

scala> val aa:Int =  0xcafebabe
aa: Int = -889275714
```

Comment: Because hex numbers are uint by default in python? (It has nothing to do with int overflow).

Comment: Try casting it as long? `val i : Long = 0xcafebabe` Seems like an integer overflow

Comment: Yep, it is integer overflow, but a new problem occurred. Please check out my updated question. @aitchnyu

Comment: Once you enter `0xcafebabe` (without the L), you have created the number as a "normal" (not long) integer.  Converting it to Long later doesn't change its value.

Answer (score 5):

Python has arbitrary-precision integers, so the range of `int` is unlimited, akin to the `BigInt` of Scala, whereas in Scala, unqualified integer literals map to Java type `int`. Java `int` has 32-bits of precision with range -0x80000000 to 0x7FFFFFFF.

Since `0xcafebabe` and `0xdeadbeef` have the sign bit set, they are **negative** as `int`s in Java and other JVM languages; they are evaluated as the [two's complement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement), as `-0x21523502`. This is not a question of overflow, but standard behaviour. In JVM there are no unsigned value types, and `int` is used for bitfields where all 32 bits can be set, tested and unset as needed; for such cases it is customary to use a positive hex constant to set all values from `0x00000000` for no bits set to `0xFFFFFFFF` for all bits set.

In Scala, you can have positive `0xcafebabe` if you make it a `Long` literal: try `0xcafebabeL`. This will be understood as `3405691582L` by Scala.

In JVM the overflow is well-defined for math operations; the calculations happen according to the two's complement math always; you *could* consider this as an example of integer overflow, but it is not, as the compiler just considers this `0xcafebabe` to be exactly identical to the `-889275714` literal.

Comment: If it is overlow, why it doesn't throw an error as described in **P.S.2**?

Comment: Because 0xcafebabe is a negative 32bit number and 3405691582 is a positive 64 bit number, which I think follows from Antti's explanation. @Judking

Answer (score 1):

[In Python](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), integers are "bignums" that can represent numbers of any size.  (Actually in Python 2 there are integers and long integers under the hood, but conversion between them is handled transparently, so they act as a single type.)  The way Python defines integers does not tie them to a particular implementation at the bit level, and does not limit how large they may be.  [In Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/01-lexical-syntax.html#integer-literals), integers are 32-bit and longs are 64-bit.  The Scala language defines integers (and longs) as falling in a particular numerical range; numbers outside this range cannot be represented as integers in Scala.

As for your edit, once you enter `0xcafebabe` without the L suffix, you are creating a plain int.  Casting this to Long doesn't convert it to what it "would have been" if you had made it a long int initially, it just takes the value and makes it a long int.  It doesn't know how you originally input the number, so for it knows you actually typed in `-889275714`.  If you want to input a long integer *literal* you need to specify it as long when you input it.

This is also the reason you get an error for your second edit.  Again, if you don't specify the literal as long, you are inputting a regular int; if your number cannot fit into a regular int, you get an error.  (When you input the hex value, you are setting the individual bits of a 32-bit number, so you can create a negative number without using a negative sign, which is what you get when you enter a number that is "too big".)

Answer (score 0):

In Python hex numbers are UInt types by default.

Which means:

```
>>> 0xff
255
>>> 0xcafebabe
3405691582
```

I don't use Scala, but I'm guessing the default type is a 32-bit int. I.e.:

```
>>> ctypes.c_int32(0xcafebabe)
c_int(-889275714)
```

Comment: It is not really correct to say that Python ints (or hex literals) are uints.  Python ints (regardless of what literal you use to input them) do not specify an implementation at that level; they are just integers, and can be either positive or negative.

Comment: @BrenBarn Maybe that isn't perfectly worded, I meant to say that they don't use a sign bit (so in that sense a python hex number is equivalent to the corresponding c_uint). Of course it's possible to write `-0xff`