# How to print least significant 4 bits of signed integer in a file using Perl?

Tags: perl, integer, printf, 32-bit, signed

For example:

I have `$a= -1`. If I print it using `printf` with `%.4b` or `%b`, it gives me `32-bit` all 1's.

But, I only want to print the least significant 4 bits like `1111` in the file in binary.
Any ideas how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-1` in binary is represented via 2s complement, so it *is* all `1`s. (See here for more: [What is “2's Complement”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement))

If you want to 'limit' it, then the way you can do this is with a bitwise `and`.

Switching on 4 bits is

```
1+2+4+8 = 15.
```

Therefore:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $val = -1;

printf ( "%b", $val & 15 );
```

Answer (score 0):

`%.4b` refers to fractional digits, `%04b` formats to at least 4 digits, padding leading `0`s as needed.

To cater for negative integers, take the modulus by 16 ( `2^<number of least significant bits>` ).

```
my @b  = (12, 59, -1, 1 ); # sample of integers
@b = map { $_ % 16; } @b;  # take modulus
printf ("4-bits: %04b" . (", %04b" x $#b) . ";\n", @b );
                           # output with computed number of placeholders
```