# Using 2's compliment to explain operator precedence

Tags: binary, operators

I'm refreshing my knowledge on binary math and specifically two's complements.

Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12022088/4659721) post I've successfully recalled how to use two's compliment to generate the binary representation of negative of a number e.g. -15 is 11110001

Now I'm required to explain how to use two's complement to explain operator precedence in computing.

Any starter ideas?

Comment: I don't think two's complement has anything to do with operator precedence.

Comment: So do you mean apart from determining the binary equivalent of a -ve number there's no other link between 2's complement and operator precedence.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. A quick google search did not turn up anything either.