# What is a two's complement Integer?

Tags: java, types

Java Datatypes like `int`,`short`,`byte` are two's complement integers ,as they menioned it in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) . what information does it give when someone says that in java , `int` ,`short` or `byte` are two's complement integers ?

**Update :** i wanted to know why 2's complement is prefered over other representations ?

Comment: It means they are represented in memory according to strict and unambiguous rules; Google for more details.

Comment: You can find your answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement

Comment: It's a way to represent numbers in a computer that works well for positive as well as negative numbers. See [Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) on Wikipedia for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Also see [Why We Use Two's Complement](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKTsv6iVxV4) (YouTube).

Answer (score 3):

it tells you how signed values (+/-) are represented in binary form.

for example

24 in simple binary form is  00011000

- one's complement is 11100111 (inverting all bits)
- two's complement is computed by adding 1 to the one's complement value

--> 11101000 is the two's complement for -24

that's why (as an example) in java the range of a byte-value is -128 ... 127 
all values having a '1' in the 2^7 position are negative.