# Need help adding with Twos Complement notation

Tags: binary

I'm having slight confusion over two's complement. I have reviewed [What is “2's Complement”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement).

I'm trying to add -2 + -3 = -5. Here's my thought process:

```
+2 = 0010
-2 = 1110 # in twos complement

+3 = 0011 
-3 = 1101 # in twos complement

 1101
+1101
-----
10010 # What is this?
```

I know -5 is 1011 in Two's Complement. But I'm not sure what I did when I added -2 + -3 in the example above.

An explanation of the process to add -2 + -3 would be appreciated. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Your "What's this" adds `-3` and `-3`, and the answer is `11010`, not what you have. So it is `-6` - the correct answer for that sum.

Comment: Ah. I made a typo, but I see now. The way I was adding binary wasn't correct. Your comment helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 4 bit 2'scomplement -2 is 1110 and +3 is 0011 so

```
11110  carry 
 1110  -2
+0011  +3
 ----
10001  which is 0001 or simply 1 ignoring the carry in bit 5
```

Stepping through the process from the right to the left:

1. 1 + 0 results in 1 with no carry
2. 1 + 1 results in 0 with a carry of 1
3. 1 + 0 + the carry of 1 results 0 with a carry of 1
4. 1 + 0 + the carry of 1 results in 0 with a carry of 1
5. just the carry of 1 results in 1 with nothing more to carry

For reference see the Wikipedia article on 2's complement particularly the section on addition at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Addition. There are a number of online 2's complement calculators to help with conversions and one of them is at http://www.exploringbinary.com/twos-complement-converter/

Let me know if you want to see how -3 + -3 is done, since that is what you attempted.  It is a similar process, but be sure start with bit length large enough to avoid overflow as determined when the leftmost two bits in the carry row have different values.