# Convert pandas series to boolean doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

I have a data frame `df` and column `col`. The value of the last entry is `NaN`, like this

```py
df['col'][-1:]

48   NaN
Name: col, dtype: float64
```

I'm trying to apply a condition on that last value, but running this gives a `ValueError`:

```py
if dcc_td['da_4'][-1:].isna():
    print('Missing value.')
```

I did some search and it seems converting the series to boolean value may help. But running both of these conditions gives the same result:

```py
if df['col'][-1:].isna().bool():
    print('Missing value.')

Missing value.
```

And:

```py
if ~df['col'][-1:].isna().bool():
    print('Missing value.')

Missing value.
```

Further, if I run this I get `True`:

```py
df['col'][-1:].isna().bool()
```

But if I run this I get `-2`, which I expected to see `False`:

```py
~df['col'][-1:].isna().bool()
```

What did I misunderstand about these concepts?

EDIT: A simple solution for the `ValueError` issue is:

```py
if df['col'][-1:].isna().all():
    print('Missing value.')
```

But still, the boolean issue is quite helpful to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~` is bitwise operator, when you do `~True` you are actually doing `~1` which will invert the each bit from binary representation of `1`. <sup>[1]</sup>

What you want is logical operator `not`.

[1] [Why does bitwise "not 1" equal -2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31377474/why-does-bitwise-not-1-equal-2)

Comment: Thanks. It takes some time for me to understand this. In the meantime I find this `~dcc_td['da_4'][-1:].isna().all()` also gives `False`.

Comment: @NonSleeper `.all()` returns `numpy.bool_`, doing bit-wise NOT on numpy boolean can reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728708/inverting-a-numpy-boolean-array-using