# Computable Size of Integer

Tags: c, types, integer

An int32 is represented in computer memory with a size of 4 bytes (32 bits).

So, 32 bits have 1 sign bit and 31 data bits. But if 1st bit starts at 2^0, then the 31st bit should have 2^30, and the last bit is of course the sign bit.

How is it then that integer extends from -2^31 to (2^31)-1?

Comment: Read wikipage on [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: ...and here is a SO link for [Two's Complement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement)

Comment: There is an explanation for 8 bits on wikipedia. See "Some special numbers to note" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Why_it_works

Comment: @Blastfurnace the SO answer really helped. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

> So, 32 bits have 1 sign bit and 31 data bits.

No. Most platforms use [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent integers.

This avoids double zero (+- 0) and instead extends the range of negative numbers by 1. The main advantage is in arithmetic: Many operations, like addition and subtraction can simply ignore the sign.

Comment: I wouldn't say "no" : even in 2's complement representation, the official terminology is still 1 sign bit and 31 value bits. The difference between 2's complement and other representations is the meaning of the value bits in the case that the sign bit is set.

Comment: OK, maybe a *no* is a bit too harsh. Anyway, I wanted to make clear that this is the core of the OP's confusion: It's not a sign bit that just inverts the value of the rest of the bits.

Comment: @M.M Saying "sign bit" and "value bits" is not accurate.  A true sign bit would alter the meaning of the other bits, like in floating point where it means "change the value represented by the other bits from positive to negative."  But that's not how it is with 2s complement.  The value of an N-bit 2s complement number is the sum of the values represented by each of its 1 bits:  Bit 0 is worth 1, bit 1 is worth 2, bit 2 is worth 4,... until you get to bit N-1 which is worth _minus_ 2^(N-1).  The high order bit doesn't change the meaning of the others, it merely adds its value to their sum.

Comment: @jameslarge See section 6.2.6.2/2 of [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Those are the official terms.  The sign bit is `1` for negative numbers, and `0` for zero and positive numbers.

Answer (score 1):

An int32 has exactly 32 bits, and can hold 2^32 different values.

In unsigned form, these will be 0 -> (2^32)-1.
In signed form, these will be -2^31 -> (2^31)-1. Notice that:

> (0 - (-2^31)) + ((2^31)-1 - 0) =
>     2^31 + 2^31 - 1 =
>     2*2^31 - 1 =
>     (2^32) - 1

Exactly the same range.