# Why in PHP bitwise ~0=-1?

Tags: php

I thought 0 is 0000 0000 0000 in bits and the bitwise not 0 would be 1111 1111 1111 which would be a really big number rather than -1. Even if the first digit is sign digit, then it should be a really negative number rather -1. Can someone explain for me?

Comment: This is called "Twos Complement". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement for more info.

Comment: wouldn't that account ^ as a possible duplicate? @JohnHascall

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't have the rep needed to close as dup...

Comment: @JohnHascall No problemo; closed as such, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

Because 11111....111 is -1. 10000....00 is the smallest negative number. Such is the binary representation of negative numbers. It's "inverted".

See more on this link:
http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/BinaryMath/NumSys.html#signint