# What happens when I apply the unary "-" operator to an unsigned integer?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

This should be a pretty simple question but I can't seem to find the answer in my textbook and can't find the right keywords to find it online.

What does it mean when you have a negative sign in front of an unsigned int?

Specifically, if x is an unsigned int equal to 1, what is the bit value of -x?

Comment: Specifically, the bit value will be the same, regardless of whether the variable is declared as signed or unsigned int. Only the interpretation changes; the underlying binary value does not.

Comment: https://repl.it/CEPW/2

Comment: You get the only number such that `x + (-x) = x - x = 0`, so, the only reasonable result.

Answer (score 10):

Per the C standard, arithmetic for unsigned integers is performed modulo 2<sup>bit width</sup>. So, for a 32-bit integer, the negation will be taken mod 2<sup>32</sup> = 4294967296.

For a 32-bit number, then, the value you'll get if you negate a number `n` is going to be `0-n = 4294967296-n`. In your specific case, assuming `unsigned int` is 32 bits wide, you'd get `4294967296-1 = 4294967295 = 0xffffffff` (the number with all bits set).

---

The relevant text in the C standard is in §6.2.5/9:

> a  result  that  cannot  be  represented  by  the  resulting  unsigned  integer  type  is reduced  modulo  the  number  that  is  one  greater  than  the  largest  value  that  can  be represented by the resulting type

Comment: Detail: "is performed modulo 2bit width" is more accurately stated with "is performed modulo (max value + 1)".  A difference in the rare case of an unsigned integer containing padding bits.  (Something I have never seen.)

Answer (score 4):

It will overflow in the negative direction, i.e. if your `int` is 16 bits x will be `65535`. The bit value will be `1111111111111111` (16 ones)

If int is 32 bits, x will be `4294967295`

Answer (score 0):

when you apply the "-", the Two's complement of the integer is stored in variable. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement) for details

Comment: This is really trying to explain it the wrong way arround. Unsigned arithmetic is modulo, and two's complement is the sign representation that uses this simple trick.

Comment: int V1=-1;
unsigned int V2=-1;
the stored value for both V1 and V2 in memory is 0xffffffff which is the two's complement of 0x00000001.