# Difference in BigInteger values from a String and a byte array

Tags: java, android, string, arrays, biginteger

Can someone please explain the difference between the below two initialisations of BigInteger.

Input:

```
BigInteger bi1 = new BigInteger("EF", 16);
byte[] ba = new byte[] {(byte)0xEF};
BigInteger bi2 = new BigInteger(ba);
Log.d("BIGINTEGER", "Big Integer1 = " + bi1.toString(16));
Log.d("BIGINTEGER", "Big Integer2 = " + bi2.toString(16));
```

Output:

```
Big Integer1 = ef
Big Integer2 = -11
```

How can I initialise a BigInteger with the value "EF" from a byte array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [BigInteger docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

> Constructor and Description
>
> BigInteger(byte[] val)
>
> Translates a byte array containing the **two's-complement binary
>   representation** of a BigInteger into a BigInteger.

**The Two's-complement is the real reason.**

Lets see how...

`(Byte)0xef` in binary = 11101111
Now convert that back to Int and you get -17 (base 10) or -11 (base 16).

Now take a look at

```
byte[] ba = new byte[] {0, (byte)0xEF};
```

This has the `(Byte)0xef` but prepended by 0. Which means this array has 00000000 11101111, which when converted gives the correct result.

**Why was the previous case different?**

Check out 2's complement rules - [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049722/what-is-2s-complement), Mandatory [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

**Another way of thinking about this**

0xEF in Decimal = 239

Range of Byte = -127 to 128

We have Overflow.

`239 - 128 = 111`

Now count this 111 from back (Numeric data types have this circular behaviour, again due to 2's complement representation).

For example:  `129.toByte = -127`

(129 - 128 = 1, count from back the 1st value = -127)

Shortcut to counting from back `if x>128 && x<256 then x.toByte = (x - 128) - 128`

Here x =  239 so x.toByte = -17

Answer (score 0):

Put a leading zero into the `byte[]`:

```
byte[] ba = new byte[] {0, (byte)0xEF};
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/i186Jx)

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Can you please explain to me how this is different.

Answer (score 0):

> **public BigInteger(byte[] val)**
>
> Translates a byte array containing the **two's-complement** binary representation of a BigInteger into a BigInteger. The input array is assumed to be in **big-endian** byte-order: the most significant byte is in the zeroth element.
>
> **public BigInteger(String val,
>             int radix)**
>
> Translates the String representation of a BigInteger in the specified radix into a BigInteger. [...]
>
> *Source: Oracle Java 7 Docs*

Your Initialization from a bytearray does not behave as expected, because 0xEF casted to a bytearray returns {1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}.

Made to an integer according to the specs mentioned above is done as follows:

```
1*2^0 + 1*2^1 + 1*2^2 + 1*2^3 + 0*2^4 + 1*2^5 + 1*2^6 - 1*2^7 = -17 = -0x11
```

The two's-compliment causes the highest byte to be substracted, rather than being added. So adding a 0 to the beginningthe byte array should probably fix the problem:

```
byte[] ba = new byte[] {0, (byte)0xEF};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a zero into the `byte[]` array:

```
byte[] myByteArray = new byte[] {0, (byte)0xEF};
BigInteger bi2 = new BigInteger(ba);
Log.d("BIGINTEGER", "Big Integer1 = " + bi1.toString(16));
Log.d("BIGINTEGER", "Big Integer2 = " + bi2.toString(16));
```

## why?

well the reason is related to the language specification:

**Decimal** literals have a particular property that is not shared by **hexadecimal**, i.e Decimal literals are all positive [[JLS 3.10.1]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html).

To write a negative decimal constant, you need to use the unary negation operator (**-**) in combination with a decimal literal.

In this way, you can write any int or long value, whether positive
or negative, in decimal form, and negative decimal constants are clearly identifiable by the presence of a minus sign.

Not so for hexadecimal nor octal literals.
**They can take on both positive and negative values. Hex and octal literals are
negative if their high-order bit is set.**

So after having said that,  **0xFE** is actually a negative number...